# React.js onClick not working clicking span icons mapped from json table

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have icons I am mapping from a json table:

```
<ul className="major-icons">{ icons.map(function(i){
                            return <li key={i.id}><span className={i.class} id={i.id} data-id={i.data} onClick={this.onClick} onMouseOver={this.onHover}></span></li>

                                }) }

                            </ul>

var icons = [

    { data: '0', id: 'p0', class: 'icon style1 major fa-code'},
    { data: '1', id: 'p1', class: 'icon style2 major fa-bolt'},
    { data: '2', id: 'p2', class: 'icon style3 major fa-camera-retro'},
    { data: '3', id: 'p3', class: 'icon style4 major fa-cog'},
    { data: '4', id: 'sochi', class: 'icon style5 major fa-desktop'},
    { data: '5', id: 'decision_trees', class: 'icon style6 major fa-calendar'},

];
```

I have an event handler:

```
getInitialState: function() {
    return { project_id: 0};
},

onClick: function(event) {
    this.setState({ project_id: event.currentTarget.dataset.id });
    console.log("hello");
},
```

Unfortunately, even clicking these span icons, nothing is happening (not even the console.log).  What can I do?

Comment: can you try `<ul className="major-icons">{ var self = this; icons.map(function(i){
                            return <li key={i.id}><span className={i.class} id={i.id} data-id={i.data} onClick={self .onClick} onMouseOver={self .onHover}></span></li>

                                }) }

                            </ul>`

Comment: @Andrew: this still did not work

Comment: @user1072337 Nevermind. The `map` is messing with `this`. Pass in this to `map`.

Comment: @Aatif: this is not working, it's giving me an error: Unexpected token (43:52)

Comment: @Andrew: can you explain what you mean?

Comment: can you paste the complete error `unexpected token` as  ?

Comment: @user1072337 `this` isn't bound in `map`, so `this` is undefined in `map`. Thus, the click handler reference is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem with the scope of `this` inside your `map` function. The quickest way to fix your code is to preserve the scope of `this`. To make sure that `this` refers to your Component you can 1) pass `this` as a second argument to `map`, 2) use an arrow function; or 3) use the `bind` method. Here is a demo: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/jraLWZ

I would however review this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38908620/4186037 and consider refactoring the code so that we don't create a copy of the click handler for *each* item in the array on *each* re-render.

1. Pass `this`to `map` method

   ```
         <ul className="major-icons">{ icons.map(function(i) {
             return (
               <li key={i.id}>
                     <span className={i.class}
                           id={i.id}
                           data-id={i.data} 
                           onClick={this.onClick} 
                           onMouseOver={this.onHover}>
                       Some text
                     </span>
               </li>
             );
           }, this) }
   -----------^^^^
         </ul>
   ```
2. Arrow function

   ```
         <ul className="major-icons">{ icons.map((i) => {
   --------------------------------------------------^^
           return (
               <li key={i.id}>
                     <span className={i.class}
                           id={i.id}
                           data-id={i.data} 
                           onClick={this.onClick} 
                           onMouseOver={this.onHover}>
                     </span>
               </li>
             );
           }) }
         </ul>
   ```
3. Bind method

   ```
         <ul className="major-icons">{ icons.map(function(i) {
           return (
               <li key={i.id}>
                     <span className={i.class}
                           id={i.id}
                           data-id={i.data} 
                           onClick={this.onClick} 
                           onMouseOver={this.onHover}>
                     </span>
               </li>
             );
           }.bind(this)) }
   ---------^^^^^^^^^^
         </ul>
   ```

Comment: You might want to explain why this works and how `this` is affected. `map` also has an argument that allows passing in of `this` context.

Comment: Great hint - thanks Andrew :) I've updated the answer.