# Trying to call a document id from a sub-collection in firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to run a delete function that should be fairly straight forward but i'm not getting it.

I referenced the document within the sub-collection but it doesn't seemed to be referenced correctly. When I hard code the answer documents id it performs the function but when I try to reference it doesn't work.

I have the document information stored in an array but I need to cycle through the array to find the id that matches the post. I'm having trouble grabbing the reference from 'getAnswer' once it is stored.

Here is the code:

```
    const [getAnswer, setGetAnswer] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;

    db.collection("questions")
      .doc(questionId)
      .collection("answer")
      .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        if (mounted) {
          setGetAnswer(
            snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
              id: doc.id,
              answers: doc.data(),
            }))
          );
        }
      });

    return () => (mounted = false);
  }, []);

  const handleDeletePost = (e) => {
    if (user) {
      db.collection("questions")
        .doc(questionId)
        .collection("answer")
        .doc(getAnswer.id)
        .delete();
    }
  };

  const answerMenuId = "primary-answer-account-menu";
  const answerRenderMenu = (
    <Menu
      anchorEl={anchorEl}
      anchorOrigin={{ vertical: "top", horizontal: "right" }}
      id={answerMenuId}
      keepMounted
      transformOrigin={{ vertical: "top", horizontal: "right" }}
      open={isMenuOpen}
      onClose={handleMenuClose}
    >
      <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>Edit</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose} onClick={handleDeletePost}>
        Delete
      </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
  );
```

For a bit more context I would like to delete an answer document based on the id of the document. Here is a screenshot of the database:

[image]

Comment: When you are fetching data from db, you can store the question id and answer id as the key of that element like `quesID-ansID`. That way you have both and when you click on it you can easily get it as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40044861/get-key-index-on-click-es6-react). Then just split them using the `-` and pass them in the delete function?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: which answer are you trying to delete? Or are you trying to delete all answers for a specific question?

Comment: I'm trying to delete one answer for a specific question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `answerId` is a variable that is holding the document ID of the answer to delete, you're looking for:

```
const answersDocumentRef = db.doc("answer/"+answerId);
```

Or alternatively:

```
const answersDocumentRef = db.doc(`answer/${answerId}`);
```

Or (without the `answersDocumentRef`):

```
db.collection("questions")
    .doc(questionId)
    .collection("answer")
    .doc(answerId)
    .delete();
```

Or alternatively for that:

```
db.doc(`questions/${questionId}/answer/${answerId}`).delete();
```

Comment: The issue I'm having is that answerId isn't a variable and I can't seem to store it. When I try to store it via doc.id I get the parent collection id instead of the answer's

Comment: I don't understand what you mean there. Can you edit your question to show a screenshot of the document you're trying to delete in the Firestore console?

Comment: Ok, added some more information to the post

Answer (score 1):

Your `getAnswer` is an array, and it is NOT indexed by `id`.  It is an array of objects, each of which has properties `id` and `answers`, in the order the query returns documents by timestamps.

`getAnswer.id` is meaningless in this context, and it's completely unclear what `user`, `questionId` and `id` even are in the context you show.

what event are you processing?  how do you know which answer is indicated by the event?  is it a button?  select? checkbox?  radio button?

Also note: each DocumentSnapshot in the QuerySnapshot **INCLUDES** doc.ref.path, which you could pass directly for `db.doc(refPath).delete()` - no need to construct the `.collection().doc().collection()` etc etc.

I use a wrapper package for FirebaseFirestore that always includes the `doc.ref.path` as refPath in my Record objects for exactly this reason - also, you can parse it to find parent documents, etc

Comment: Added a bit more info to the post if it helps