# Why and when do we need to bind functions and eventHandlers in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-class

```js
class SomeClass extends Component{
  someEventHandler(event){
  }
  render(){
    return <input onChange={------here------}>
  }
}
```

I see different versions of `------here------` part.

```js
// 1
return <input onChange={this.someEventHandler.bind(this)}>

// 2
return <input onChange={(event) => { this.someEventHandler(event) }>

// 3
return <input onChange={this.someEventHandler}>
```

How are the versions different?  Or is it just a matter of preference?

---

Thank you all for answers and comments.   All are helpful, and I strongly recommend to read this link **FIRST** if you are confused as me about this.
http://blog.andrewray.me/react-es6-autobinding-and-createclass/

Comment: suggested reading http://blog.andrewray.me/react-es6-autobinding-and-createclass/

Comment: Do you know what `.bind` does and how `this` works?

Comment: There is also [the proposed bind operator `::`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bind-operator). Use like this: `return <input onChange={::this.someEventHandler} />`, with [the appropriate Babel transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-function-bind/).

Comment: https://gist.github.com/fongandrew/f28245920a41788e084d77877e65f22f suggested reading

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Binding is not something that is specifc to React, but rather how `this` works in Javascript. Every function / block has its own context, for functions its more specific to how its called. The React team made a decision for `this` to not be bound on custom methods on the class (aka not the builtin methods like `componentDidMount`), when adding ES6 support (class syntax).

When you should bind the context depends on the functions purpose, if you need to access props, state or other members on the class, then you would need to bind it.

For your example, each is different and it depends on how your component is set up.

### Pre binding to your class

`.bind(this)` is used to bind the this context to your components function. However, it returns a new function reference each render cycle! If you don't want to bind on each usage of the function (like in a click handler) you can pre-bind the function.

**a.** in your constructor do the binding. aka

```
class SomeClass extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.someEventHandler = this.someEventHandler.bind(this);
    }
    someEventHandler(event){
    }
    ....
}
```

**b.** make your custom functions on the class fat arrow functions. aka

```
class SomeClass extends Component{
    someEventHandler = (event) => {
    }
    ....
}
```

### Runtime binding to your class

few common ways to do this

**a.** you can wrap your components handler function with an inline lambda (fat arrow) function.

```
onChange={ (event) => this.someEventHandler(event) }
```

this can provide additional functionality like if you need to pass additional data for the click handler `<input onChange={(event) => { this.someEventHandler(event, 'username') }>`. The same can be done with `bind`

**b.** you can use `.bind(this)` as described above.

```
onChange={ this.someEventHandler.bind(this) }
```

with additional params `<input onChange={ this.someEventHandler.bind(this, 'username') }>`

If you want to avoid creating a new function reference but still need to pass a parameter, its best to abstract that to a child component. [**You can read more about that here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29810951/2733506)

### In your examples

```
// 1
return <input onChange={this.someEventHandler.bind(this)}>
```

This is just doing a runtime event handler bind to your class.

```
// 2
return <input onChange={(event) => this.someEventHandler(event) }>
```

Another runtime bind to your class.

```
// 3
return <input onChange={this.someEventHandler}>
```

You are just passing the function as the callback function to trigger when the click event happens, with no additional parameters. Make sure to prebind it!

To summarize. Its good to think about how to optimize your code, each method has a utility / purpose depending on what you need.

Answer (score 21):

**Why bind a React function?**

When you define a component using an ES6 class, a common pattern is for an event handler to be a method on the class. In JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default. If you forget to `bind this.someEventHandler` and pass it to `onChange`, this will be undefined when the function is actually called.

Generally, if you refer to a method without `()` after it, such as `onChange={this.someEventHandler}`, you should bind that method.

There three ways to bind your `onChange` function to the correct context

**First**

```
return <input onChange={this.someEventHandler.bind(this)}>
```

In this one we make use of `bind` explicitly to function to make the onChange event available as an argument to the eventHandler. We can also send some other parameter with type of syntax like

```
return <input onChange={this.someEventHandler.bind(this, state.value)}>
```

**Second**

```
return <input onChange={(event) => { this.someEventHandler(event) }>
```

This is a ES6 syntax, whereby we can specifythe parameters that we want to pass to the `someEventHandler` function. This is equivalent to `.bind(this)` however, It also gives us the flexibility to send other attributes along with the event like

```
return <input onChange={(event, value) => { this.someEventHandler(event, value) }>
```

**Third**

Define the function someEventHandler using Arrow function

```
someEventHandler = () => {
    console.log(this); // now this refers to context of React component
}
```

An `arrow function` does not have its own `this`, the `this` value of the enclosing execution context is used and hence the above function gets the correct context.

or **bind it in constructor** like

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.someEventHandler = this.someEventHandler.bind(this);
}


return <input onChange={this.someEventHandler}>
```

In this method, event is directly attached to the `someEventHandler` function. No other parameters can be passed this way

Comment: @JohnRuddell I did not get your point. Maybe I missed something. Could you explain a little

Comment: Ok yea, so basically `.bind(this)` is only passing **context** and has nothing to do with the arguments passed. For instance if I did this `onClick={this.someEventHandler.bind(this)}` then the handler function would have my context passed to it (aka `this`) but also has the event passed to it as the first argument. so... `someEventHandler(event) { console.log(event) }` would be the click event on the input element. `.bind(this)` just makes it so in that function your `this` **context** is the class context

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri What do you mean when you say "In JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default" ?