# Why an arrow function solves what otherwise would require a .bind? (SetInverval calling a function that uses setState)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React docs implements a clock for demonstrating concepts such as states and lifecycle.

```js
class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {date: new Date()};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(
      () => this.tick(),
      1000
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState({
      date: new Date()
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <h2>It is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Clock />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I was curious about why `componentDidMount`'s setInterval uses an arrow function. It does't work without it, either by:

Implementation ONE:

```js
setInterval(this.tick(), 1000)
```

Which passes the return of `tick` instead of calling it, either by doing:

Implementation TWO:

```js
setInterval(this.tick, 1000)
```

Which throws an `setState is not a function` error.

It was [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45780551/setinterval-function-without-arrow-function) on stackoverflow, but the accepted answer is wrong, since it suggests coding IMPLEMENTATION TWO.

I guess the error is caused due to the scope of `this`. Inside setInterval, there's no `this.setState`, that's why binding solves it (as one of the others answers point out).

However, I would like to know how an arrow function can solve what otherwise would require binding.

Comment: In an arrow function, `this` is lexically scoped like any other variable. So inside the arrow function, `this` refers to `this` of `componentDidMount`.