# Can we access props passed to the component in a custom function

Tags: reactjs

this may sound silly but I can't find a guide to this.

what I'm trying to do is changing a variable named `update` in parent.

and in the parent DOM do :

```
 <Child update={this.state.update} />
```

and in the child instead of picking it up between render and return (with `const {update} = this.props`) and only being able to use it in the DOM, I'd like to pick it up in the  section between the constructor and render and use it in a function there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the `props` to the component anywhere in the component whether it be the `constructor, lifecycle functions, render or custom functions.`

The only thing that you need to know is that `constructor, lifecycle methods and render function` are already have `binding` to the context of the React component, but for `custom function` you need to add binding yourself. Binding can be done in the `constructor` or by declaring the functions as `arrow functions`.

Check this answer on why you need to bind custom functions: [Why do we need to bind function and eventHandlers in React and what is the difference between the different binding methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41113798/why-do-we-need-to-bind-function-and-eventhandlers-in-react-and-what-is-the-diffe/41113862#41113862)

For your case

```
<Child update={this.state.update} />
```

where Child could be

```
class Child extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const {update} = this.update || {};
        console.log(update);
        this.somefunc();
    }
    somefunc = () = {
       const {update} = this.update || {};   //After function is binded, you can do the same thing here too
        console.log(update);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use it in `componentWillReceiveProps(NewProps)` when I try to console.log it either from `NewProps.update` or `props.update` `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined`

Comment: What is `this.state` doing inside the constructor of `Child`?

Comment: nevermind I had to make sure to exclude another function from the declaration that's why

Comment: You can remove the constructor altogether if all it does is call `super`.

Answer (score 1):

React has a lifecycle of functions called on a component: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

On startup of component you can use `componentDidMount()`

if you want to change state based on props change use: `componentWillReceiveProps()`

Otherwise if you want the result of that function to use as data for in your view (but just manipulated). Than make a seperate function also called: computed property of computed function. (because the result is computed based on current state/props). React will make sure you don't re-render/compute unnecessary.

Comment: I'm trying to use it in `componentWillReceiveProps(NewProps)` when I try to console.log it either from `NewProps.update` or `props.update` `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined`

Comment: @tatsu that is very weird i wonder how your code looks like. this is not normal. also you should use `this.props.update` ofcourse

Comment: I figured it out it's because i was trying to instantiate a function from newProps aswell even though it didn't come from there.