# getting error: Cannot read property state of undefined

Tags: reactjs, undefined, state, typeerror

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import FormUpdate from "../components/formUpdate";
import { fetchClothingItem, updateClothingItem } from "../actions/crud";

export default class Update extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          updateClothingItem: {}
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        fetchClothingItem(this.props.match.params.postId)
        .then(data => {
        this.setState(state => {
          state.updateClothingItem = data;
          return state;
        });
        console.log("data", data);

        //HERE IT IS RETURNING EXPECTED DATA       

        console.log("this.state.updateClothingItem",this.state.updateClothingItem)    
          })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error("err", err);
        });
    }

    handleSubmit(data) {

        //HERE IT IS THROWING: 

        > "TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined"

        console.log("this.state.updateClothingItem", this.state.updateClothingItem);
            updateClothingItem(this.state.updateClothingItem.id, data); this.props.router.push("/update");
    }
    render() {
        return (
        <div>
        <FormUpdate
          //onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}
          id={this.state.updateClothingItem.id}
          name={this.state.updateClothingItem.name}
          sleeveLength={this.state.updateClothingItem.sleeveLength}
          fabricWeight={this.state.updateClothingItem.fabricWeight}
          mood={this.state.updateClothingItem.body}
          color={this.state.updateClothingItem.color}
        />
        <button
          type="submit"
          onClick={this.handleSubmit}
          className="addItemButton"
        >
        Button
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

There are a few things that are technically wrong in terms of React code implementation.

**Firstly,** With ES6 style of writing a class, any function that needs to access the Class properties need to be explicitly `binded`. In your case you need to bind the handleSubmit function using `arrow function` of or `binding in constructor`.

See this answer for more details: [Why and when do we need to bind functions and eventHandlers in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41113798/why-do-we-need-to-bind-function-and-eventhandlers-in-react-and-what-is-the-diffe/41113862#41113862)

**Secondly:** You have your async request set up in the componentWillMount function and in the success response of it, you are setting state. However using `setState` in `componentWillMount` is triggered after the component is rendered so you still need to have an undefined check. You should instead make use of `componentDidMount` lifecycle function for async requests.

Check this answer on whether to have **[AJAX request in `componentDidMount` or `componentWillMount`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47392910/is-it-ok-to-make-ajax-calls-in-componentwillmount/47393005#47393005)**

**Third:** setState is asynchronous and hence logging the state values after the setState function won't result in the correct output being displayed. Use the `setState callback` instead.

See these answers for more details:

[calling setState doesn't mutate state immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278385/updated-state-not-reflecting-after-setstate/41278440#41278440)

[When to use React setState callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038590/when-to-use-react-setstate-callback/42038724#42038724)

Code:

```
export default class Update extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          updateClothingItem: {}
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetchClothingItem(this.props.match.params.postId)
        .then(data => {
        this.setState(state => {
          state.updateClothingItem = data;
          return state;
        });
        console.log("data", data);

        //HERE IT IS RETURNING EXPECTED DATA       

        console.log("this.state.updateClothingItem",this.state.updateClothingItem)    
          }) // this statement will not show you correct result since setState is async 
        .catch(err => {
            console.error("err", err);
        });
    }

    handleSubmit = (data) =>  { .    // binding using arrow function here

        console.log("this.state.updateClothingItem", this.state.updateClothingItem);
            updateClothingItem(this.state.updateClothingItem.id, data); this.props.router.push("/update");
    }
    render() {
        return (
        <div>
        <FormUpdate
          //onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}
          id={this.state.updateClothingItem.id}
          name={this.state.updateClothingItem.name}
          sleeveLength={this.state.updateClothingItem.sleeveLength}
          fabricWeight={this.state.updateClothingItem.fabricWeight}
          mood={this.state.updateClothingItem.body}
          color={this.state.updateClothingItem.color}
        />
        <button
          type="submit"
          onClick={this.handleSubmit}
          className="addItemButton"
        >
        Button
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this binding thing makes me go mad each time I use functions to access state data, this is so **** weird syntactically coming from traditional languages and UI frameworks background

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to bind your `handleSubmit` function to the class. You can either use arrow function to define the function.

```
handleSubmit=(data) =>{
...
}
```

Or you can bind the function in your constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          updateClothingItem: {}
        };
        this.handleSubmit= this.handleSubmit.bind(this,data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no state in constructor yet

if you want to set state in constructor you can do it like this

```
class SomeComponent extends Component {
   constructor(props){
      super(props)

      this.state = { someKey: someValue }
   }
}
```

or even like this

```
class SomeComponent extends Component {

   state = { someKey: someValue }

}
```

but in this case babel should be properly configured

Comment: What is the difference between these two? I face issues with the first example.

Comment: @Jesse just updated my answer - ... meant there should be some values