# Use componentWillMount or componentDidMount lifecycle functions for async request in React

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I am reading up on react lifecycle and am getting a little confused. Some recommend using componentWillMount to make ajax calls:

https://hashnode.com/post/why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-call-setstate-immediately-after-componentdidmount-in-react-cim5vz8kn01flek53aqa22mby

> Calling setState in componentDidMount will trigger another render()
>   call and it can lead to layout thrashing.

and in other places it says not to put ajax calls in the componentWillMount:

https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-reactjs-component-life-cycle-823a640b3e8d

> ...this function might end up being called multiple times before the
>   initial render is called so might result in triggering multiple
>   side-effects. Due to this fact it is not recommended to use this
>   function for any side-effect causing operations.

Which is correct?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The React docs recommend on using `componentDidMount` for making network Requests

> `componentDidMount()` is invoked immediately after a component is
> mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you
> need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to
> instantiate the network request.
>
> Calling `setState()` in this method will trigger an extra rendering, but
> it is guaranteed to flush during the same tick. This guarantees that
> even though the `render()` will be called twice in this case, the user
> won’t see the intermediate state.

As per the case for `componentWillMount`:

**EDIT:**

This lifecycle is deprecated since `v16.3.0` of react and is no longer encouraged for usage.However its renamed to `UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate` and is expected to work till at least **v17** of react

**Before v16.3.0**

An asynchronous call to fetch data will not return before the render happens. This means the component will render with empty data at least once.

There is no way to “pause” rendering to wait for data to arrive. You cannot return a promise from `componentWillMount` or wrangle in a `setTimeout` somehow. The right way to handle this is to setup the component’s initial state so that it’s valid for rendering.

**To Sum it up**

In practice, `componentDidMount` is the best place to put calls to fetch data, for two reasons:

- Using DidMount makes it clear that data won’t be loaded until after
  the initial render. This reminds you to set up initial state
  properly, so you don’t end up with `undefined` state that causes
  errors.
- If you ever need to render your app on the server, `componentWillMount` will actually be
  called twice – once on the server, and again on the client – which is
  probably not what you want. Putting the data loading code in
  `componentDidMount` will ensure that data is only fetched from the
  client.

Comment: Thank you for the extra explanation :)

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

`componentDidMount` is the recommended lifecycle method to make Ajax calls as described in [their docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

Answer (score 1):

ComponentDidMount is the place.

But if you have time try to look at Redux and make the requests in actions, as your application grow it will help a lot to manage the app state.

;)

Comment: Yes, I am using redux and calling actions, but they have to be invoked somewhere... I am trying to figure out where the best place is to put them. :)

Comment: @RodolfoLeal don't write comments in answer section