# Unable to render content from api call in componentDidMount()

Tags: reactjs

This is a simplified version of a problem I've faced while working in React. When I'm making a fetch call inside `componentDidMount()` and updating the state with the payload as follows:

```
componentDidMount(){
    fetch("/api/endpoint").then(data => {
        return data.json();
        }).then(json => {
            this.setState({
                data: json
            });
    });
}
```

And rendering it out in `render()`:

```
render(){
    return(
        <p>{this.state.data.title}</p>
    )
}
```

I get an error saying `this.state.data is undefined`. I got around it by wrapping it around a conditional operator as follows:

```
{ this.state.data !== undefined ? <p>{this.state.data.title}</p> : null }
```

But my question is, if `componentDidMount()` fires before `render()` then how can `this.state.data` ever be undefined?

Comment: Did you set the state in constructor ?

Comment: Yes I did. You reckon that might have something to do with it?

Comment: `componentDidMount` fires after `render` but it doesn't wait for your api call. It's not blocking. So you will need to handle the in-between state explicitly. Either checking for null just as you did or show a `loading` message until your data arrives.

Comment: Ah makes sense now. So this is a common phenomenon then, right?

Comment: I believe you are looking for this best practise: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidMount()` runs after `render()`. You need to initialize the state correctly in the constructor

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data: {title: "" } };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
      fetch("/api/endpoint").then(data => {
          return data.json();
          }).then(json => {
              this.setState({
                  data: json
              });
      });
  }
  render(){
    return(
        <p>{this.state.data.title}</p>
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: I don't think that's the issue here. Even if you treat `this.state.data` as a string, it will still return undefined.

Comment: Initializing the state in this manner won't return undefined, unless the fetch call is returning undefined

Answer (score 0):

> But my question is, if componentDidMount() fires before render() then how can this.state.data ever be undefined?

The order of `componentDidMount` firing before or after `render` doesn't really matter here. `componentDidMount` has async effects. Let's say it always fires before `render`, then what happens is this:

`componentDidMount` is run. It runs `fetch`. Running `fetch` doesn't make the browser wait for `fetch` to return and do `setState`. Instead `fetch` sends the request to the server, and returns a *promise* that will be fulfilled when the response from the server returns.

The code that runs when the promise is fulfilled is the function you pass as an argument to `.then()`. Since your `setState` call is inside `.then()`, it will only run once the response it available.

Meanwhile, your browser goes ahead and calls `render`. The response from the server may or may not have returned and resolved the promise (most probably it won't have returned because network is slower than the processor executing code). So `render` gets called with `this.state.data` not yet defined. So you need to consider a state where `data` is `undefined` in `render`.

Answer (score 0):

> But my question is, if componentDidMount() fires before render() then
>   how can this.state.data ever be undefined?

You assumption/understanding that `componentDidMount` lifecycle function fires before render is wrong, `componentWillMount` is fired before render while `componentDidMount` is fired after the render method. Now you might say that since `componentWillMount` is fired before render, I can move my fetch call in `componentWillMount` and thus I would not have to add a check in the render method, but that not right. Even though your request is fired before the render the response may not always be available before the render function is executed and since all of these happen `asynchronously` you need to add a check for the data in render method

```
render(){
    return(
        <p>{this.state.data? this.state.data.title: null}</p>
    )
  }
```

Check [Use componentWillMount or componentDidMount lifecycle functions for async request in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47392910/use-componentwillmount-or-componentdidmount-lifecycle-functions-for-async-reques/47393005#47393005) question for more details