# How to see the effect of componentDidMount() in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

To realize the effect of componentDidMount(), I wrote the following code segment:

```
class Blink extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {output: 'c'};
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.state.output += 'w';
  }
  render() {
    this.state.output += 'r';
    let display = this.state.output;
     return (
       <Text>{display}</Text>
     );
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.state.output += 'd';
    this.setState();
  }
}

export default class BlinkApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Blink text='I love to blink' />
        <Blink text='Yes blinking is so great' />
        <Blink text='Why did they ever take this out of HTML' />
        <Blink text='Look at me look at me look at me' />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

I expected to see four lines of 'cwrdr' according to two reasons:

1. The execution order: constructor(props)->componentWillMount()->render()->componentDidMount()
2. setState() called in componentDidMount() will invoke render() again.

Please kindly share your thoughts on my code and reasoning. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You've made the mistake of mutating state, by using this line `this.state.output += 'd';`. By doing so, React no longer knows when it is time to trigger a re-render of your application.

Instead, you want to use `setState({output : this.state.output + 'd'})`. This assigns a new object to your state, and render will work as expected.

Also, you should remove the `this.state.output += 'w';` from the `componentWillMount` lifecycle. You should **NOT** do any state-changing operations in this lifecycle method, as it will not trigger a re-render.

> componentWillMount() is invoked immediately before mounting occurs. It is called before render(), therefore setting state in this method will not trigger a re-render. Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in this method.

Comment: `You should NOT do any state-changing operations in this lifecycle method, as it will trigger an endless re-render loop and crash your application.` This is incorrect

Comment: @DragoşPaulMarinescu Thanks for your answer. That inspired me to do some small experiments. I tried to replace this.state.output statement with setState call in each lifecycle method, and observed the following findings: (1) such a change did not affect componentWillMount(); both did work; (2) we could not use setState() in render(), which produced an error where maximun update depth was exceeded; however, this.state.output worked just fine; (3) in componentDidMount(), just as you said, this.state.output was not correct and only this.setState() worked so that I saw 'cwrdr'.

Answer (score 1):

**First of all** you should not mutate the state directly. According to the docs:

> Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may
>   replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were
>   immutable.

**Secondly:** The reason you don't see `'cwrdr'` in render is because `this.setState()` no longer triggers a re-render from v16 onwards. From the [blog post](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html#breaking-changes)

> Calling setState with null no longer triggers an update. This allows
>   you to decide in an updater function if you want to re-render.

**Lastly:** Don't `setState` in `componentWillMount` synchronously, do it in constructor instead.

> `componentWillMount()` is invoked immediately before mounting occurs. It
>   is called before `render()`, therefore setting state in this method will
>   not trigger a re-render. Avoid introducing any side-effects or
>   subscriptions in this method.

Also avoid using componentWillMount as much as possible since from v16.3.0 onwards react has proposed to rename it and deprecate it from v17 onwards. Check [this answer on where to place async Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47392910/use-componentwillmount-or-componentdidmount-lifecycle-functions-for-async-reques/47393005#47393005)

Comment: `this.setState() no longer triggers a re-render from v16 onwards`. That's not true. It no longer triggers a re-render if you call it with `null`. That's different.

Comment: @DragoşPaulMarinescu, please check this codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/01l8nkv83p