# converting react classes to functions with redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm still new to react/redux, after getting something like this to function

User.js

```
class User extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.fetchUser(.....);
}

render() {
    return (
        <Profile />
    )
}

export default connect(null, {fetchUser})(User);
```

Profile.js

```
class Profile extends React.Component {
    render() {

        const { user } = this.props

        return (    
                <h1>{user.profile.name}</h1>
        )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    user: state.store.user
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(Profile)
```

actions.js

```
export const fetchUser = (.....) => dispatch => {
    fetch()
    .....
}
```

reducers.js

```
case FETCH_USER:
    return {
        ...state,
        user: action.payload.user
    };
```

As I understand it, the User component calls an action (fetchUser) from connect on componentWillMount(). That action calls an api, gets the data and the reducer adds that to the store within the state. The Profile component can then use connect to map the data from fetchUser in the store and display that data.

After reading some tutorials including https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.md

It looks like things can be simplified a bit without using classes.

If I were to change the User and Profile components to a more functional way, how would I do it?

eg.

```
const User = () => {
    return (
        <Profile />
    )
}
```

how do I dispatch the fetchUser action and how do I simulate it to be called with the flow of componentWillMount()?

or am I just over complicating things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is also a way to support lifecycle methods in functional components.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pure-lifecycle

```
import React from 'react';
import lifecycle from 'react-pure-lifecycle';

 // create your lifecycle methods
const componentDidMount = (props) => {
   console.log('I mounted! Here are my props: ', props);
};

// make them properties on a standard object
const methods = {
  componentDidMount
};

const FunctionalComponent = ({children}) => {
return (
  <div>
    {children}
  </div>
 );
};

// decorate the component
export default lifecycle(methods)(FunctionalComponent);
```

Comment: its creating class based HOC using class based component https://github.com/planttheidea/react-pure-lifecycle/blob/master/src/components.js.Its not functional component

Comment: From user perspective this library provides an HOC to plug lifecycle method to their already written functional component. Writing a class is the cleanest in my opinion as well.

Comment: Advantage from using this according to the library is `Not a whole lot of gain here other than the fact that you now have a pure function that you can test independently (no need to create an instance). This decoration method will also work on PureComponents`

Comment: We can do same things with our reusable HOC

Answer (score 1):

I think,`User` component is designed nicely.It will act as a container for `Profile` to provide the Data.

Instead of making `Profile` component class oriented,it should be  `Stateless`.

Lets `User` component pass the required data for `Profile` component.
You don't need to connect `Profile` component using `redux-connect`.Just render it as a `Child component of User`.

**Profile**

```
const Profile = (props) => {

  const {user, likeProfile} = props;
  //likeProfile()//call like this using dom event or programmatically.
  return (
    <h1>{user.profile.name}</h1>
  )
}
```

You need to make some changes in `User` component.
Get the state for `Profile` component via `mapStateToProps`.

```
class User extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
      this.props.fetchUser(.....);
}

render() {

  const {user, likeProfile} = this.props;
  return (
      <Profile user= {user} likeProfile={likeProfile} /> //passed the user data to Profile component vua User
  )
}
```

**Map the user state for  `Profile` in `User` connect.**

```
const mapStateToProps = (state)=>{
  return{
    user : state.somereducerkey.user //this will be accessible in Profile via props { user}
  } 
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchUser, likeProfile})(User);
```

Comment: I was wondering about this one, let's say my Profile component has an action like likeProfile(), how do I pass that action from the User component to the Profile component?

Comment: @totalnoob  I have updated answer assming `likeProfile` call.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should keep using statefull components with redux...
https://medium.com/@antonkorzunov/2-things-about-purecomponent-you-probable-should-know-b04844a90d4

Redux connect — is a PureComponent.
Yes — a very important thing, a HoC for a molecule is a pure one. And works even inside other pure components. And gets store from a current context.

Same is working, for example, for styled-component — you can wrap it with PureComponent, but it will still react to Theme changes.

Solution is simple — bypass logic, use old school events bus, subcribe, wait and emit events.

Styled-componets:

```
componentWillMount() {      
// subscribe to the event emitter. This      
// is necessary due to pure components blocking 
// context updates, this circumvents      
// that by updating when an event is emitted.

   const subscribe = this.context[CHANNEL];
   this.unsubscribe = subscribe(nextTheme => {  <----- MAGIC
React-redux:

trySubscribe() {
 if (shouldSubscribe && !this.unsubscribe) {
  this.unsubscribe = 
     this.store.subscribe(this.handleChange);  <----- MAGIC
 }
}
componentDidMount() {
  this.trySubscribe();
}
```

Thus, even if parent Pure Component will block any update enables you to catch a change, store update, context variable change, or everything else.

So — something inside pure components is very soiled and absolutely impure. It is driven by side effects!
But this bypass straight logic flow, and works just differently from the rest of application.

So — just be careful. And don’t forget about magic.

Aaaand….
And this is a reason, why any redux store update will cause redraw in each connected component, and why you should use reselect just next to connect HoC —

to stop unnecessary change propagation.
But you should read this from another point of view:

redux-connect is a source of a change propagation.
redux connect is the end of a change propagation. It is still PureComponent.
And this leads to quite handy thing — you can control change propagation with redux-connect only. Just create a boundaries for a change. Lets talk about this in another article.

Conclusion
Pure components keep your application fast. Sometimes — more predictable, but often — less predictable, as long they change the way application works.

Stateless components are not pure, and may run slower than PureComponents by any kind.

But… if you very wish to create a fast application with good user experience — you have to use Pure Component.

No choice. But, now — you know hidden truth, and knew some magic…

Answer (score 1):

1. `React` recommends that ajax request be made in `componentDidMount()`, rather than in `componentWillMount()`. For more info on this, read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47393005/2076046).
2. Since you want to make ajax requests in `componentDidMount()`, you need a class. There are two ways of writing component definitions: functional component and the class component. Functional components are more concise, but you don't get component lifecycle methods like `componentDidMount()`. Think of it as just a render function that takes props as inputs and outputs `DOM`s (in JSX). To override those lifecycle methods, you need to define them as a class.
3. If you want to use `Redux`, and want to make ajax requests in a Redux action, you should `import` the action creator function (`fetchUser(..)` in your case) that makes the ajax request, and `dispatch(fetchUser(..))` in `componentDidMount()`. `connect(..)`ed components get `dispatch(..)` function passed to it by `Redux store`.

If you want to see how it's done in other redux apps, see the official example apps in the redux.js repo, paying attention to `actions` and `containers`: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples

Answer (score 1):

> In Your case you can continue with **statefull components** no wrong in that
>   ,If you need to go with **functional way**

There is a work arround

https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/162

**Suggestion**

> Calling the api in componentDidMount will make sense than
>   componentWillMount , Because you can show the user something is
>   fetching.