# Change loading state after function call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 3 API calls in a function `fetchData`. How do I set the loading state to false after executing the following code:

```js
componentWillMount() {
  this.setState({ loading: true })
  this.fetchData()
  //after these two calls, I want to set the loading State to false
}
```

- All the API calls are each a promise
- Using React 14.3

Comment: In `this.fetchData()` you probably have some kind of promise, when it resolves then set your loading state to false. See [promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: Yes, all the calls are a promise.
I have looked into promise.all after your reply. Thank you. It does serve my purpose.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> 1. I used es8 **async await function**. Inside that, You can use **Promise.all** to resolve the all promises.

```
  fetchData = async () => {
    const a = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => { console.log('one'); return resolve("done!"); }, 1000)
    });

    const b = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => { console.log('two'); return resolve("done!"); }, 2000)
    });

    return await Promise.all([a, b]) ? true : false;
  }
```

> 2. Write the logic in componentDidMount instead of componentWillMount. you can use fetchData function as a
>    promise. After that you can set state whatever you want.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ loading: true })
    this.fetchData().then((result)=>{
      console.log(result, 'three');
      this.setState({ loading: false });
    });
  }
```

You can see working example [click here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-willmount?file=index.js)

Comment: Your working example was very helpful. I tried changing a few things which helped me understand the use of async-await here.

Also, I should be using componentDidMount, right?

Comment: Yes, that is the correct place to make a api call. componentWillMount will deprecate in future. Even in react 16.3, its shows warning.

Comment: I'm glad, it helped you. 

Comment: Can you please clarify the use of returning true / false instead of just Promise.all[a, b]?

Comment: @AzadRahman You can return anything you want. It's totally depend on use case. You can return await Promise.all([a, b]). Use stackblitz and try to play around code to understand more.

Comment: Didn't know about stackblitz till now. I used to use codesandbox.
I did play around, which clarified a lot of things. Thank you. I hope someone upvotes this. :'3

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Redux you could have your reducer set `loading: false` after the API calls return.

See [for more info](http://gavinschulz.com/posts/2017-03-22-4-techniques-for-loading-states-in-redux.html)

Comment: Not using Redux

Answer (score 0):

You should make the API calls on componentDidMount as componentWillMount is set to be deprecated.

```
FetchData() {
  APIcalls.then(() => {
     This.setState({ loading: false })
   })
 }
```

Comment: Yes, i just checked the Docs. I'll change it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You would make use of `async-await` and use `componentDidMount` instead of componentWillMount since this method is likely to be replaced in react v17 
Also check this question

[Use componentWillMount or componentDidMount lifecycle functions for async request in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47392910/use-componentwillmount-or-componentdidmount-lifecycle-functions-for-async-reques/47393005#47393005)

```
async componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({ loading: true })
  await this.fetchData()
  this.setState({ loading: false });

}

async fetchData() {
    await ApiCall1();
    await ApiCall2();
    await ApiCall3();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I just checked the React Docs, and yes, you are right. Should use ComponentDidMount.

Can you please clarify where I should set the state of loading to false?
Thank you.

Comment: Also I'd like to know which one would be a better solution: using async-await, or using promise.all?

Comment: @AzadRahman, I updated my answer, Also async-await is the latest syntax, Also you can use async await or promise.all or both of them together, its upto you. There is no major performance benefit