# React js state and lifecycle

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
componentDidMount() {
    const user = auth.getCurrentUser();
    this.setState({ user });
  }
```

I have this code, I think `this.setState({ user });`takes a little time, if I want to do some checks immidetly like

```
<Route
              path="/foo"
              render={props =>
                this.state.user ? (
                  <Bar {...props} />
                ) : (
                  <Redirect to="/login" />
                )
              }
            />
```

when refreshing the page the user at the beginning is always null. what is the proper solution? do I need to set state at `constructor`? or did I do something wrong?

My account got blocked by some down votes questions, the funny thing is I have to re-edit them, even though I already have the accepted answer.I do not understand what's the point to do this.I am so frustrated by this stackoverflow system.

Now, I basically can do nothing but keep editing my questions, and they have all been answered. This is ridiculous !!!

Comment: _"do I need to set state at constructor?"_, did you try it and how about the result?

Comment: Use callback or use async/await. Also change this.setState({ user }) to this.setState({ user: user });

Comment: @NguyễnThanhTú yes I did it's working. if I set state in the `constructor`, just wondering what's the best practices

Comment: @parth there is nothing to do with async and await. there is no promise in that function. and this `this.setState({ user });` is valid js code

Comment: @AndySong I think I know what you're trying to do. Well then, this article might help:https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-protected-routes-authentication/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when refreshing the page the user at the beginning is always null

@Shubham Khatri did explain it really well, in short, just because the `render()` function is called before the `componentDidMount()`, hence, the `user` is always null.

Take a look at this: [React lifecycle methods diagram](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/)

[image: React lifecycle methods diagram]

And as you can see that, the proper place for `setState` should be the `contructor()` cuz it's called before the `render()`.

> However, for api calls why `componentDidMount` is the better place? why
>   we do not do all set up in `constructor`?

I know you're talking about this: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html . The document does say that: *You should populate data with AJAX calls in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method. This is so you can use `setState` to update your component when the data is retrieved.*

However, [in another place](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount), they say:

> You may call `setState()` immediately in `componentDidMount()`. It will
>   trigger an extra rendering, but it will happen before the browser
>   updates the screen. This guarantees that even though the `render()` will
>   be called twice in this case, the user won’t see the intermediate
>   state. Use this pattern with caution because it often causes
>   performance issues. **In most cases, you should be able to assign the
>   initial state in the `constructor()` instead.** *It can, however, be*
>   *necessary for cases like modals and tooltips when you need to measure*
>   *a DOM node before rendering something that depends on its size or*
>   *position.*

...and also for the case that you need to authenticate because this process depends on the value of the `user` ( as your design).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should initialise your state in the constructor.

See the [React docs example](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class):

```
class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {date: new Date()};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <h2>It is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: hi, I know, it's working. so what I did in `componentDidMount` is wrong right? when I make api calls we usually do it in `componentDidMount` and when we do some checks immidetly , I should do it in `constructor` ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that, `componentDidMount` is called after render and by the time your user details are fetched and stored in state, your component is ready to redirect to `/login` since user wan't available. To solve this issue, you need to fetch `user` details before the initial render and hence `constructor` is the ideal place to do it

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
       user: auth.getCurrentUser()
   }
}
```

Comment: however, for api calls why `componentDidMount` is the better place? why we do not do all set up in `constructor`?

Comment: @AndySong Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47392910/use-componentwillmount-or-componentdidmount-lifecycle-functions-for-async-reques/47393005#47393005

Answer (score 0):

The state goes inside the constructor, but only if you need a constructor (e.g.:to initialize flags). If you don't need a constructor you can just initialize the state outside:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    state = { myState = [] }

    render() {
        const { myState } = this.state
        return (...)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the constructor() to initiate state, componentDidMount() for call functions and componentWillReceiveProps() for setState.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.userProfile();
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, prevProps) {
    this.setState({
      firstName: nextProps.user.firstName,
      lastName: nextProps.user.lastName
    });
  }
```