# Where should we make an API request in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have always made `API's` request in `ComponentDidMount` lifecycle and called `setState` in the callback. But while digging deep I happened to find out We should not call setState in this lifecycle as it triggers render method again and React also doesn't recommend that.

Then in that case where exactly we should make that request and call `setState` to use result after that?

Comment: componentDidMount is correct.

Comment: you are incorrect about not making api calls in componentDidMount. It is the right method to make API calls

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47392910/use-componentwillmount-or-componentdidmount-lifecycle-functions-for-async-reques/47393005#47393005

Comment: Even though you make API calls in constructor or componentWillMount which are called before constructor there is no gurantee that the response is received before render and a re-render is anyways triggered on setState

Comment: You may call setState() immediately in componentDidMount(). It will trigger an extra rendering, but it will happen before the browser updates the screen. This guarantees that even though the render() will be called twice in this case, the user won’t see the intermediate state. Use this pattern with caution because it often causes performance issues. In most cases, you should be able to assign the initial state in the constructor() instead.  -  React doc

Comment: @indar What it talks about is the setState without an async call in componentDidMount

Comment: @Adnanshah you are wrong, since componentWillMount is being deprecated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should absolutely make an API call in `componentDidMount`. What is not recommended is to re-render a big component, instead what you should do is break your UI into small logical components and only re-render only what is needed , not a whole. For example, you have a big component named `HomeComponent` which has 3 small components called `NavComponent`, `BodyComponent` and `FooterComponent`. You should **NOT** be calling the API from the `componentDidMount` of the `HomeComponent` since calling `setState` from `HomeComponent` will re-render all the small components inside `HomeComponent`, which is not necessary since you know that the navbar or footer is not needed to be re-rendered. Rather from the `BodyComponent`, because only the body part needs to be re-rendered since its state has changed. So you should be calling the API from the `componentDidMount` of the `BodyComponent`, that way you re-render only whats needed.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I do take this approach of splitting UI into small components so child components don't get rendered unnecessarily. But I thought there would be any different approach community is using. :)

Answer (score 0):

@Shababb Karim is right but if i were to implement API calls in my project i would add a state management library. Redux is a great way to implement a global state to the app where you can set data from said API. All components that need that data can be attached to the Redux state to get it.

Redux can be a bit of overhead in smaller projects though. In this case there are other options like Flux (although i like Redux more).