# How to setState in child component when child function called from parent component in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, function, components, setstate

I want to call child function from parent component so I found a question here

[Call child method from parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949981/call-child-method-from-parent)

So I used this way to to called it (From 1st Answer and 2nd approach).

Now issue is how to set state in the child `getAlert` function

```
class Parent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child ref={instance => { this.child = instance; }} />
        <button onClick={() => { this.child.getAlert(); }}>Click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends Component {
  constructor(){
     super();
     this.state = {message:""};
  }

  getAlert() {
    alert('clicked');
    //HERE I NEED TO SETSTATE 
  }

  render() {
    return (
      {this.state.message!=""?(
         <h1>{this.state.message}</h1>

      ):(

      <h1>Hello</h1>

      )}
    );
  }
}
```

In the getAlert function of child I need to setState but I couldn't able to do it. Please provide any solution

Comment: setState of the parent or the child itself

Comment: I assume the problem is about binding. bind the function getAlert

Comment: can you post the code snippet how to resolve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that when calling `setState` inside the getAlert function of child, `this.setState` will come undefined. This happens because `this` inside your getAlert function doesn't refer to the context of the React Component and setState is defined for the Component. You can solve this by binding the `getAlert` function.

You can do it in two ways.

**First:** using `.bind(this)` in constructor

```
class Child extends Component {

  constructor() {
     super();
     this.getAlert = this.getAlert.bind(this);
  }
  getAlert() {
    alert('clicked');
    //HERE I NEED TO SETSTATE 
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    );
  }
}
```

**Second:** use Arrow function

```
getAlert = ()  => {
    alert('clicked');
    //HERE I NEED TO SETSTATE 
  }
```

Check this answer on **[Why do we need to bind React functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41113798/why-and-when-do-we-need-to-bind-functions-and-eventhandlers-in-react/41113862#41113862)**

Check the working snippet

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child ref={instance => { this.child = instance; }} />
        <button onClick={() => { this.child.getAlert(); }}>Click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
     super();
     this.state = {message:""};
  }

  getAlert = () => {
    alert('clicked');
    this.setState({message: "somemessage"});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.state.message!=""?(
         <h1>{this.state.message}</h1>

      ):(

      <h1>Hello</h1>

      )}</div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"/>
```

Comment: What error do you get, can you elaborate your problem

Comment: No error, I just did that you wrote. I put these line inside getAlert function this.setState({message:"Yahoo"}); console.log(this.state.message); so console.log always print blank

Comment: In that case you need to see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278385/updated-state-not-reflecting-after-setstate/41278440#41278440

Comment: console.log is not my concern. My concern is about state update if state is not updating then render of child component doesn't work. Please look at the edited question then you will understand state use

Comment: Thanks, may be there is some other issue in my code need to look again.

Answer (score 1):

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child ref={instance => { this.child = instance; }} />
        <button onClick={() => { this.child.getAlert(); }}>Click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
  super()
  this.state = {
    message: 'google'
  }
  this.getAlert = this.getAlert.bind(this)
  }
    
  getAlert() {
    alert('clicked');
    this.setState ({
      message: 'yahoo'
    }, () => {
      console.log(this.state.message) //the state value will be printed
    }); 
  }

  render() {
  console.log(this.state.message)
    return (
      <h1>Hello {this.state.message}</h1>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

you have bind the getAlert() method to scope of the class ie). 'this'.  I have added an sample code..pls check

Comment: No error, I just did that you wrote. I put these line inside getAlert function this.setState({message:"Yahoo"}); console.log(this.state.message); so console.log always print blank

Comment: try using console.log() inside callback of setState function or inside render() method.  Because setState behaves asynchronously so the new state will not be available if u log it immediately

Comment: console.log is not my concern. My concern is about state update if state is not updating then render of child component doesn't work. Please look at the edited question then you will understand state use

Comment: I have added a working fiddle for the same..pls check