# What's difference between two ways of defining method on React Class in ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions, ecmascript-next, class-fields

I see this a lot in ES6 React code

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  bar = () => {
    console.log("bar")
  }

  baz() {
    console.log("baz")
  }
}
```

Seems like they both define methods `bar` and `baz` on `Foo` but how are they different.

Comment: The first one is not ES6.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use arrow functions (public class fields) as class methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31362292/1048572)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The declarations differ in how the function are written and the `context` of `this`,

In the first syntax

```
bar = () => {
    console.log("bar")
  }
```

the function is written using [`Arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) syntax.

> An arrow function does not have its own `this`; the `this` value of
>   the enclosing execution `context` is used. Hence `this` keyword inside
>   this function will refer to the context of the `React class`

However the second declaration

```
baz() {
    console.log("baz") 
}
```

is a simple function and `this keyword` in this function refers to the context of the function itself.

So when you try to access React class Properties/functions like `this.state` or `this.setState` you will get an error in the second case(if you haven't used binding anywhere else for this function(example constructor)) whereas it would work in the first case since for an arrow function, `this` means the same thing within the function body as it does outside of it. Which means that if you use arrow functions within your component’s custom functions, they can use `this` and `this.setState` with no surprises.

Check this answer on **[why you need to bind functions in React classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41113798/why-and-when-do-we-need-to-bind-functions-and-eventhandlers-in-react/41113862#41113862)**

Comment: `you will get an error in the second case(if you have used binding...`. I guess you mean `you will get an error in the second case(if you have not used binding...`

Comment: @Prakashsharma, yes that was a typo on my behalf, updated it

Comment: Also defining a method using arrow function, actually makes it an instance property that happens to be a function, rather than adding it as a method to the prototype, this is important distinction if you ever want to subclass your component, you wont be able to access `super.bar()` it in the subclass

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm wondering how render() method can use the scope of `this` of component. As `this.state` works in `render()` method even though it's not a arrow function. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @Malleswari, render and lifecycle methods are already binded to the correct context in their implementation and hence you dont need to bind them

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers are absolutely correct and are why you would want to be using arrow functions in react classes.

I just wanted to also point out a subtle difference that is a potential pitfall of their use in a class to avoid surprises...

Arrow functions defined on a class are **added to the instance as a property** that just so happens to be a function, whereas defining not as an arrow function will **add the function as a method to the class's prototype**.

In React components that will never be extended this is fine, but if the case arises you want to subclass a component, you will not be able to override an arrow function expecting to be able to call the base class via `super`, you can only overwrite it in its entirety

```
class Button extends React.PureComponent {

    // class method - overridable in subclass
    pressMethod: function(): void {
      console.log('beep')
    }

    // instance property functions - only overwriteable in subclass
    pressArrow = (): void => {
      console.log('boop')
    }

    pressArrowTwo = (): void => {
      console.log('blip')
    }

  }


  class BigRedButton extends Button {

    // class method - overides subclass one, 
    // can call superclass method via `super`
    pressMethod: function(): void {
      super.pressMethod() // prints 'beep' to console
      console.log('BOOOOOOOOM!!!')
    }

    // instance property function
    // cannot call superclass via `super` as lambda's have no prototype
    pressArrow = (): void => {
      super.pressArrow() // TypeError - not a function
      console.log('BOOOOOOOOM!!!')
    }

    // completely overwrites instance property of same name in subclass
    // doesn't try to access prototype so won't error but is limited
    pressArrowTwo = (): void => {
      console.log('BOOOOOOOOM')
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, both are equal:

1. bar = () => { ...  }
2. this.bar =this.bar.bind(this)