# Redux function is part of props, but then undefined

Tags: reactjs, function, redux, react-redux, react-props

Hey I have a issue i cant wrap my head around..

I have a action in redux called updateIpBrowserConfig.

I pass it to my container and then to a child component.

When I do this in my child component:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(this.props);
}
```

I sure enough get all the props and I can see that the updateIpBrowserConfig is a function:

```
{options: Array(3), ipBrowserConfigSelected: 1, updateBrowserIpConfig: ƒ}
```

But if I do also in the constuctor

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(this.props);
    console.log(this.props.updateBrowserIpConfig);
}
```

I get exactly the same props object that shows updateBrowserConfig as a function, but the value when printing the function is "undefined".

So I cant fire the action, because the function is undefined. But it is in my props as a function?

I cant wrap my head around this. Hopefully someone can help

Comment: Could you add code for parent container?

Comment: Possibly what you are looking for is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41113798/why-and-when-do-we-need-to-bind-functions-and-eventhandlers-in-react/41113862#41113862

Comment: Not really because, it is reference to function that is undefined, not reference to variables used in function, that are bound to this in parent function. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I guess `this` is coming undefined, Am I wrong

Comment: Can you add your parent component from where you are passing the updateBrowserIpConfig