# React-native - passing props undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to pass a username between two files but it remains undefined. Where am I going wrong? Thanks!

//Login file

```
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
          credentials: {
            username: "",
            password:"",

          }
        }
        this.navigate = this.props.navigation.navigate;
    }


      signIn(){
          {....}
          this.navigate("main", {
                username: this.state.username,
              });
        }

  }
```

In Main:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    this.navigate = this.props.navigation.navigate;
    this.params = this.props.navigation.state.params;
}
{...}
    render() {
    console.log(this.params.username);
    //here it's undefined
```

Comment: What value your are getting in `this.props.navigation.state.params`?

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not an object(evaluating this.props.navigation.state.params.username)

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the params incorrectly in Main component, you need to access from `this.props.navigation.state.params`, you would get it like

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    this.navigate = this.props.navigation.navigate;
    this.params = this.props.navigation.state.params;
}
{...}
render() {
console.log(this.props.navigation.state.params.username);
```

Comment: I changed it to that and now I'm getting TypeError: undefined is not an object(evaluating this.props.navigation.state.params.username)

Comment: Did you bind the signIn function in Login component

Comment: I'm not sure, how do I do that?

Comment: you would write, `this.signIn = this.signIn.bind(this)` in the constructor(), check this for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41113798/why-and-when-do-we-need-to-bind-functions-and-eventhandlers-in-react/41113862#41113862

Answer (score 0):

Use `params` while `navigate()` to pass the parameters.

```
this.navigate({
   routeName: 'main',
   key: 'main',
   params: { 
      username: this.state.username
   }
});
```

To access it use `this.props.navigation.state.params.username`.

Hope this will help!

Comment: I think I have it exactly like that but I'm still getting undefined is not an object Constructor in LogIn: this.navigate = this.props.navigation.navigate;. Constructor in main: this.navigate = this.props.navigation.navigate;
    this.params = this.props.navigation.state.params; and then trying to print it: console.log(this.props.navigation.state.params.username);

Comment: Can you please share how you have defined the navigation?

Comment: For now I have very little logic but it's a button that is connected to this function:   signIn(){
    if(this.state.username === undefined){
      alert("Username can't be empty")
    } else {
      console.log(this.state.username)
      this.navigate("main", {
        params: {
        credentials: this.state.username,
        }
      });

Comment: No no, I was asking how u have used `StackNavigator` or `TabNavigator` to define routes.

Comment: const mainOptions = SwitchNavigator({
  main : Main,
  favPlaces : favPlaces,

})
const introStack = StackNavigator({
  loggingIn : LoggingIn,
  register : Register
})

const SwNavigator = SwitchNavigator({
  login : introStack,
  main : mainOptions

})