# what is difference between this.eventTapped.bind(this) and this.eventTapped?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am working with the following event handler:

```
eventClicked(event) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(event));
}
```

I am trying to figure out what is difference between using `.bind(this)` and not binding the `this` context in the above **event handler**.

I have tried both approaches and they both yield the same result. So, why we use `.bind(this)`?

Comment: Please read this [article](https://medium.com/@denny.headrick/this-bind-this-a-javascript-story-313ff84a12c8)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why and when do we need to bind functions and eventHandlers in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41113798/why-and-when-do-we-need-to-bind-functions-and-eventhandlers-in-react)

Comment: bind is a javascript function that allows you to attach a this object. What that means is that if your handler is going to be called in a different context you can make sure it still uses the correct this object.