# Call the function and get method after receiving the data in componentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Expected effect: 
In `componentDidMount ()` I download `s` and saves in the variable`timeId`. If `timeId` is true, pass`this.state.timeId` to the `loadTime ()` function to `https://app/load-id/${id}` and call this function. The data returned by this function is saved in the variable `checkId`. `this.state.checkId` transfers to the`Details` component.
Problem: how to call the function `loadId ()`, after receiving data in `componentDidMount ()`?

**App**

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      checkId: '',
      timeId: ''
    }
  }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios({
            url: `https://app`,
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
              'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        })
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
              timeId: res.data.id,
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        }) 

    }

  loadId =  (id) => {  //id ---> this.state.timeId
    axios({
        url: `https://app/load-id/${id}`,   
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`           
        }
    })
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.setState({
            checkId: response.data
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })
}



  render () {

    return (
        <div>
            <Item

            />

            <Details 
                checkId = {this.state.checkId}  
            />
        </div> 
    )
  }
}
```

**Details**

```
class Details extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        task: ''
    };
  }


  componentDidUpdate(previousProps, previousState) {
    if (previousProps.checkId !== this.props.checkId) {

        this.setState({
            task: this.props.checkId
        })
    }

  render() {
    return (
        <div >

        </div>      
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41113798/why-and-when-do-we-need-to-bind-functions-and-eventhandlers-in-react/41113862

Comment: just call it after you get the id? `.then(res => this.loadId(res.data.id))` also @Michael haha small world that link is to my answer :)

Comment: Nice!  Still doubt that happens much.

Comment: @JohnRuddell yes ;  if 'res.data.id' is true

Comment: is it an id or a boolean?

Comment: @JohnRuddell  It  is `id`. In componentDidMount(), `https://app` --> sometimes return null,

Comment: @JohnRuddell `Null` breaks down applications because, for example, id does not exist

Comment: So either handle the invalid id in componentDidMount before passing to the next function, or let loadId handle an invalid id. Not sure what the issue is with your current question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call loadId inside the then function.

```
    axios({
        url: `https://app`,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    })
    .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          timeId: res.data.id,
        });
        this.loadId(res.data.id);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind `loadId()` to set state and call it when request in `componentDidMount()` returns response:

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      checkId: '',
      timeId: ''
    }

    this.loadId = this.loadId.bind(this); // Bind here
  }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios({
            url: `https://app`,
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
              'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        })
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
              timeId: res.data.id,
            });
            this.loadId(res.data.id); // Call loadId
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        }) 

    }

  //...
}
```