# TypeError: this is undefined "React"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, es6-modules

Getting type error, but when I use **onClick={()=>this.clickHandler()}** works like charm. So what happened when I use **onClick={()=>this.clickHandler()}** and whay I am getting error by writing  **onClick={this.clickHandler}**

[image]

```
constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.clickHandler}>Class click</button>
                {/* <button onClick={()=>this.clickHandler()}>Class click</button> */}
            </div>
        )
    }

    clickHandler(){
        this.logPrint()
    }
    logPrint(){
        console.log("click the button");

    }
```

Comment: Missing bind in react

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why and when do we need to bind functions and eventHandlers in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41113798/why-and-when-do-we-need-to-bind-functions-and-eventhandlers-in-react)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973648/react-this-is-undefined-inside-a-component-function

Answer (score 2):

Two ways to achieve this

Use arrow functions

```
clickHandler: () => {

}
```

Bind method with component's `this` in constructor

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use arrow functions for event handlers, they will bind this automatically:

```
clickHandler = () => {
    this.logPrint()
}
```