# React: onClick handler is getting called on every render?

Tags: reactjs

I am learning React, and followed [this tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html) to create a simple Tic-Tac-Toe game that you can [view here in CodePen.](http://codepen.io/attkom/pen/ygeovW?editors=0010)

I am confused about how the arrow function works in the `onClick` property of the Square component that is being returned inside of the `renderSquare` function of the Board component: `onClick={() => this.props.onClick(i)}`. And also again similarly the Game component where I have `onClick={ (i) => this.handleClick(i)}`. I assumed I could write it without the arrow function (just like `onClick={this.handleClick(i)}`) but this breaks the game.

Comment: Rough explanation: `onClick` takes a function that is executed on event trigger. When `() => this.foobar(blah)` is done, that *creates an arrow function* that executes `foobar` with arguments `blah`. The reason you can't do `{this.foobar(blah)}` is because that will execute the function and pass the return value. `onClick` needs a function execute, not a value.

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29810914/react-js-onclick-cant-pass-value-to-method

Comment: You might also want to have a read https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`onClick` expects a function. An arrow function does not have its own `this`; the `this` value of the enclosing execution context is used.
Arrow function is a replacement for the following

```
onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this,i)}
```

It doesn't work when you run it like

```
onClick={this.handleClick(i)}
```

because in this case it will call a function and that will pass a return value that will be evaluate everytime render is called. So if you are doing somethings in the onClick function that causes a rerender for instance `setState` you app will go in an endless loop. Thus `onClick` needs a function and not a value so unless you are returning a function from the `onClick` handler you should not directly call it.

Arrow function above performs the role of binding the parameter to the function

Comment: I think this conclusion cannot be reached without knowing what is inside the `handleClick`, it might as well give you a new function callback back as a value. Ofcourse it fits the question, but it really depends on what the `handleClick` function is doing

Comment: @Icepickle, yes you are right, This is an old answer of mine which didn't have that explanation, I was in the process of editing it with more details.