# React JS OnBlur Error

Tags: reactjs

I have the following script :

```
class GlobalSearch extends Component {
    search_blur(){
        console.log("inside_blur_function");
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="search-container">
                <input type="search" onBlur="{this.search_blur}"/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

But, when I run the script, it returns the following error :

> **Uncaught Error**: Expected onBlur listener to be a function, instead got type string

I had googled around to find the solutions for a couple hours, but couldn't find any correct solutions. Any pointers?

Comment: Did you read the error? I suggest reading up a basic React tutorial for XML tag attributes and expressions in {}...

Comment: Dude, I did know how to read the error, but didn't know what the correct solution was, just because you're good at ReactJS you don't have to be that arrogant. Even an expert could have made a slight mistake.

Comment: Not trying to be arrogant, I'm trying to tell you to do research before asking here.

Comment: I did for a couple hours, did you ever read my whole post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is self explanatory, `onBlur` expects a function as an argument and you are provinding a string. You need remove quotes around the function defined for onBlur

```
<input type="search" onBlur={this.search_blur}/>
```

Comment: Wow, can't believe it, the solution is so simple, I just need to remove the double quotes, thanks man, you saved my day :)

Comment: I need about 10 minutes before I can accept your solution, it's stackoverflow rule. I will accept the solution later.

Comment: No Problem, Glad to have helped :) You may probably need to bind the function as well later, if you make use of state inside it

Comment: You can refer to the follwing solution on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41688366/react-what-is-this-arrow-function-doing-in-the-props-for-tic-tac-toe-game/41688664#41688664

Comment: Thanks for the tips, it's quite frustating when you have to solve something, but the deadline is so close enough. Some people are helpful enough to make the others frustated, but you're the opposite, many thanks.