# React. Managing state with onClick function using index

Tags: javascript, reactjs, indexing, onclick, state

Okay, So I am still fairly new to coding. I am trying to manage the state of my calculator using an onClick function. I have a list of ingredients in my database. I have it set up so I can pull all of them from the db and its listed on my component. I am trying to set it so when i click on the individual name it will change the properties listed below. I feel like im on the right track but cant seem to figure it out.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import $ from 'jquery';
    import '../index.css';

    class StepFive extends Component{
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            ingredients: false,
        counter: 0
      }
     }

      componentDidMount() {
          var self = this;
           $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:3002/api/ingredients',
      })
      .done(function(ingredients){
            self.setState({ingredients: ingredients})
      })
    }

    handleChange(e){
      this.setState({counter: e.target.value})
    }


    listAll(){
      return (
        <div>
          <div className="vertical-menu">
          {this.state.ingredients.map(function(ingredients, i){
            console.log(i)
            return <div>
              <span><a key={i} href="#" onClick={this.handleChange(i)}>{ingredients.name}</a> <a href='#'>+</a></span>
            </div>
          })}
        </div>
      </div>)
    }

    render() {
      console.log(this.state, 'in render')
      if(this.state.ingredients === false){
        return(<div><span>loading</span></div>)
      } else {
          return(
            <div className='stepFiveBox'>
              {this.listAll()}
              <ul>
                <li>Hardness=
                  {this.state.ingredients[this.state.counter].hardness}</li>
            <li>Cleansing={this.state.ingredients[this.state.counter].cleansing}</li>
            <li>Condidtion={this.state.ingredients[this.state.counter].condition1}</li>
            <li>Bubbly={this.state.ingredients[this.state.counter].bubbly}</li>
            <li>Creamy={this.state.ingredients[this.state.counter].creamy}</li>
            <li>Iodine={this.state.ingredients[this.state.counter].iodine}</li>
            <li>INS={this.state.ingredients[this.state.counter].ins}</li>
            <li>Lauric={this.state.ingredients[this.state.counter].lauric}</li>
            <li>Myristic={this.state.ingredients[this.state.counter].myristic}</li>
            <li>Palmitic={this.state.ingredients[this.state.counter].palmitic}</li>
            <li>Stearic={this.state.ingredients[this.state.counter].stearic}</li>
            <li>Ricinoleic={this.state.ingredients[this.state.counter].rincinoleic}</li>
            <li>Oleic={this.state.ingredients[this.state.counter].oleic}</li>
            <li>Linoleic={this.state.ingredients[this.state.counter].linoleic}</li>
            <li>Linolenic={this.state.ingredients[this.state.counter].linolenic}</li>
            <li>NaOH SAP={this.state.ingredients[this.state.counter].sap}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      )
    }
      console.log(this.listAll(),)}
  }
  export default StepFive
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React: What is this arrow function doing in the props for Tic-Tac-Toe game?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41688366/react-what-is-this-arrow-function-doing-in-the-props-for-tic-tac-toe-game)

Comment: when I change this the website renders, but when i click the ingredient. i am getting error can not read property handleChange of undefined... so i believe the issue is with my handleChange function?

Answer (score 0):

A problem is in your onClick handler. You're doing

`<span onClick={this.handleChange(i)}></span>`

Which is invoking handleChange *at render time*.

In order to invoke the function on click, you just pass the function without calling it.

`<span onClick={this.handleChange(i)}></span>`

In order to pass *specific arguments* to the function, you have two options:

`<span onClick={() => this.handleChange(i)}></span>`

or:

`<span onClick={this.handleChange.bind(this, i)}></span>`

Here's an example using the `.bind` syntax:
https://codesandbox.io/s/Z461QVox8

Comment: when I change this the website renders, but when i click the ingredient. i am getting error can not read property handleChange of undefined

Answer (score 0):

can you try to replace this one :

```
handleChange(e){
   this.setState({counter: e.target.value})
}
```

to this one :

```
handleChange = (e) => {
   this.setState({counter: e.target.value})
}
```

and replace this one too :

```
<a key={i} href="#" onClick={this.handleChange(i)}>
```

to this one :

```
<a key={i} href="#" onClick={() => this.handleChange(i)}>
```

Hope can help you :)

Comment: im still getting the same error. can not read property 'handleChange' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

it was this issues.

in the listAll function i added a

`var self = this;`

then switched all this to self. was getting error value undefined... so i realized i didnt need e.target.value i jsut needed e. 
changed handelChange function to

`handleChange = (e) => {
       this.setState({counter: e});
    }`

badabingbadaboom