# What is the difference using return a function and call the function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some code as below

```
var React = require('react');

var Controls = React.createClass({
propTypes: {
    countdownStatus: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    onStatusChange: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
},

onStatusChange(newStatus) {
    return ()=>{
        this.props.onStatusChange(newStatus);
    }
    // this.props.onStatusChange(newStatus);
},

render() {
    var {countdownStatus} = this.props;
    var renderStartStopButton = ()=>{
        if(countdownStatus == 'started') {
            return (
                <button className="button secondary"
                    onClick={this.onStatusChange('paused')}
                >Pause</button>
            )
        } else if(countdownStatus == 'paused') {
            return (
                <button className="button primary"
                    onClick={this.onStatusChange('started')}
                >Start</button>
            )
        }
    }

    return(
        <div className="controls">
            {renderStartStopButton()}
            <button className="button alert hollow"
                onClick={this.onStatusChange('stopped')}
            >Clear</button>
        </div>
    )
}
})

module.exports = Controls;
```

My question is in the function of onStatusChange(newStatus), It will be wrong to use the commented statement other than return an anonymous function. But I can not get what is the difference between return a function and call the function directly.

Anyone could please help to explain the difference? thank you very much!

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41688366/react-what-is-this-arrow-function-doing-in-the-props-for-tic-tac-toe-game/41688664#41688664

Comment: Thanks Shubham, it works now

Answer (score 1):

You can call it directly by changing your `onStatusChange(newStatus)` into an arrow function also.

```
onStatusChange => (newStatus) {
  this.props.onStatusChange(newStatus);
}

<button className="button secondary"
   onClick={() => this.onStatusChange('paused')}
 >Pause</button>
```

OR by

```
<button className="button alert hollow"
   onClick={this.onStatusChange.bind(this,'stopped')}
 >Clear</button>
```

The reason is that arrow function binds the context, here it's bind `this` and passing whatever in the parameter list. In the second example, if you are not using arrow function you have to pass `this` along with the parameter(s).

Comment: Hi Syam Pillai, thanks for your reply. Your solution 2 and 3 are good to pass test. But the first solution, I found I still need to bind it onClick to get it work. For the arrow function, do  you mean " onStatusChange: (newStatu)=>{ this.props.onStatusChange(newStatus)} " ?  It will be error if I use onClick={this.onStatusChange('stopped')}.  But it will be good to use onClick={()=>{this.onStatusChange('stopped')}

Comment: Ohh yes, my mistake. The first one can only use with the second one since you have to pass a parameter

Comment: Looks like do not need to use arrow function for onStatusChange itself.