# React Native - why do functions trigger automaticly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

Let me start up by saying that i just started learning React Native, and for that, i will try to be as explicite as possible.

## Context:

i'm trying to create a simple sign in/sign up page, i have a home screen that contains 2 Inputs with React State (userName and password) that i need to pass to a service when i press on a button, so the code look like this :

```
function HomeScreen(props) {
  const [userName, onChangeUserNameText] = React.useState(null);
  const [password, onChangePasswordText] = React.useState(null);
  ...
  return (
        <TextInput 
          ...
          onChangeText={onChangeUserNameText}
          value={userName}
        />
        <TextInput
          ...
          onChangeText={onChangePasswordText}
          value={password}
        />
        <Button
          ...
          onPress={SignIn(userName, password)}
        />
    )
```

the SignIn(...) method is exported from another file that i called home.service that should handle the communiation between my home screen and the API calls, i also put some logs in that function.

## Problem:

for some reason, whenever i load the application, or updated any of my inputs, the function that should be executed when i press on the sing in button is getting executed

**on load**

[image]

**on Change Text**

[image]

what am i missing here ?

## Edit/Conclusion :

Tank you @Robin Zigmond, the porblem was as this gentelman said, in the way i called my functions in the onPress event:

```
<Button
    ...
    onPress={() => SignIn(userName, password)}
/>
```

Comment: `SignIn(userName, password)` executes the function, so of course it gets executed every time your component renders. What you need is `onPress={() => SignIn(userName, password)}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React: onClick handler is getting called on every render?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41688366/react-onclick-handler-is-getting-called-on-every-render)

Comment: You are a life saviour !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a callback, otherwise SignIn will keep executing:

```
function HomeScreen(props) {
  const [userName, onChangeUserNameText] = React.useState(null);
  const [password, onChangePasswordText] = React.useState(null);
  ...
  return (
        <TextInput 
          ...
          onChangeText={onChangeUserNameText}
          value={userName}
        />
        <TextInput
          ...
          onChangeText={onChangePasswordText}
          value={password}
        />
        <Button
          ...
          onPress={() => SignIn(userName, password)}
        />
    )
}
```