# Send two values onClick React

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29810914/react-js-onclick-cant-pass-value-to-method) answer for sending a single value to a function onClick. Is it possible to send two? I've tried

```
        <button value={valueA, valueB } onClick={ () => this.toggleEditing.bind(this, valueA, valueB) } className="slds-button slds-button--icon">
        <svg className="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">
          <use xlinkHref={closeIcon}></use>
        </svg>
          <span className="slds-assistive-text">Cancel</span>
        </button>
```

But my second argument in `toggleEdit()` is the mouse event.

Comment: I recommend to learn what `.bind` does: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind .

Comment: @FelixKling thank you for the recommendation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can pass n no of values in `onClick` event, like this:

```
<button value={valueA, valueB } onClick={this.toggleEditing.bind(this, valueA, valueB,...) }
    className="slds-button slds-button--icon">
        <svg className="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">
            <use xlinkHref={closeIcon}></use>
        </svg>
        <span className="slds-assistive-text">Cancel</span>
</button>

toggleEditing(value1, value2, ....., event){
    console.log(value1,value2,....);
}
```

Or use `arrow function` like this:

```
onClick={(e) => this.toggleEditing(valueA, valueB,...)}
```

Answer (score 0):

> But my second argument in toggleEdit() is the mouse event.

Thus :

```
  onClick={ (valueB) => this.toggleEditing(valueA, valueB) }
```

Instead of :

```
  onClick={ () => this.toggleEditing.bind(this, valueA, valueB) }
```

Comment: The `apply` example is incorrect, it should be `this.toggleEditing.apply(this, [valueA, valueB])`. `call` is actually unnecessary and the last example is just silly (sorry). `() => this.toggleEditing(this, valueA, valueB)` would be the most reasonable thing to do.

Comment: How you guess that `this` is the 1ˢᵗ argument of `toggleEditing` not the scope ? as you note, questioner does not disclose the logic of `toggleEditing`

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my comment. I meant to write that `() => this.toggleEditing(valueA, valueB)` would be the most reasonable solution (I forgot to remove `this`).

Comment: great! this is what i expect

Comment: I'm getting an error when I use the solution "Invalid left-hand side in arrow function parameters"

Answer (score 0):

Don`t mix ES5 and ES6, just use arrow function:

```
onClick={(e) => this.toggleEditing(valueA, valueB)}
```

Comment: *"Don`t mix ES5 and ES6"* That's difficult, since ES6 mostly consists of things that existed in ES5 :P

Comment: Because it's difficult, we can see ugly code sometimes ;) I mean just use ES6

Comment: Why poke ES5 and ES6 topics in this answer  This is the catastrophe 

Comment: *"I mean just use ES6"* And my point is that ES6 is a superset of ES5. Anything that is part of ES5 is also part of ES6. That's why a statement like "just use ES6" (instead of ES5) doesn't make sense.

Comment: I don't argue with that fact. I vote for harmonized coding style. Sry for this chaos and off top.