# Pass additional param function while using constructor in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have multiple inputs; how can I know which input is changed? I think one way to do it is I can pass additional param to my handleChange function.  I know I can do this in jsx `onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'name');` But I don't know how to do that since the constructor had bind the function.

```
class HelloWorldComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(){
    super();

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      name:"",
      age:""
    }
  }

  render() {
    const person = {"name":"james", "age":18};
    return (   
      <div>
      <input onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" placeholder="name" defaultValue={person.name} /><br />
      <input onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" placeholder="age" defaultValue={person.age} />
      </div>
    );
  }

  handleChange(e){
    // how to get name and age here?
    console.log(e.target.value)
  }
}
```

http://jsbin.com/cubofurihu/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React js onClick can't pass value to method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29810914/react-js-onclick-cant-pass-value-to-method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bind` does not do any call for the function , it just assignes the scope `this` to the function .

Then , Don't write  `onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'name')}`

But , write as following:

```
onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, 'name')}
```

assuming `handleChange` is :

```
   handleChange(e, param) {
      console.log(e.target.value); 
      console.log(param) // 'name'
   }
```

Comment: handleChange(param) {

  } how can I access event here? cannot right?