# Dynamically generated input onChange function loses additional argument context

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass `option.title` as a parameter to the `onChange` function of the corresponding generated `RadioGroup` form component.

`onChange` receives the correct event, but the `option.title` value is simply the last one that's rendered. How do I bind the `option.title` to it's component's `onChange`? Presently, when an event is triggered, `option.title` has taken the last generated element's value - and this is shown regardless of what element triggered the `onChange`.

```
generateList(){
        var list = []  
        for (var i in configs){
            var option = configs[i]
            list.push(
                <div>
                <div className="optionTitle">{option.title}</div>
                <RadioGroup onChange={(e) => this.handleRadioChange(option.title, e)}  className="configContainer" horizontal>
                    {this.generateRadio(option.options, option.title)}
                </RadioGroup>
                </div>
            ) 
        }
        return list
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
generateList(){
        return configs.map((option) =>
                (<div>
                <div className="optionTitle">{option.title}</div>
                <RadioGroup onChange={(e) => this.handleRadioChange(option.title, e)}  className="configContainer" horizontal>
                    {this.generateRadio(option.options, option.title)}
                </RadioGroup>
                </div>
            ) )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [function currying](https://medium.com/@kbrainwave/currying-in-javascript-ce6da2d324fe) to access both parameters:

```
handleRadioChange(title){
   return function(e){
      // both the event and the title are accessible here
   }
}

generateList(){
                return configs.map((option) =>
                        (<div>
                        <div className="optionTitle">{option.title}</div>
                        <RadioGroup onChange={this.handleRadioChange(option.title)}  className="configContainer" horizontal>
                            {this.generateRadio(option.options, option.title)}
                        </RadioGroup>
                        </div>
                    ) )
}
```

Keep in mind that invoking function in render will create an instance on each render.
Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45448802/3148807) for more details.