# Error in onClick event in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use `onclick` event like below

```
<button className="mini ui button" onClick={this.view(item['id'])}>
   <i className="user icon"></i>
   View
</button>
```

This is creating error like below

[image]

But below code is not creating error

```
<button className="mini ui button" onClick={this.view}>
     <i className="user icon"></i>
     View
</button>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React js onClick can't pass value to method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29810914/react-js-onclick-cant-pass-value-to-method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to `onClick={() => this.view(item['id'])}`, otherwise the function gets executed immediately during rendering (instead of onClick), which causes repeated re-rendering if the function changes the state/props.

Comment: Thanks @riwu. I faced this issue, the function gets executed immediately during rendering.

Comment: Thanks @riwu. Could you please explain this code `onClick={() => this.view(item['id'])}` ? I am new in react.js

Comment: `onClick` accepts a function. I'm using ES6 arrow function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use arrow function as previews answer or you can use `bind`

```
<button className="mini ui button" onClick={this.view.bind(this, item['id'])}>
   <i className="user icon"></i>
   View
</button>
```

These two ways works.