# Pass parameter to method in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm exploring option on how is the most elegant/readable way to pass parameters to a React class method without compromising on performance.

Let's say I have two `Arrow` components to switch between items. Each `Arrow` listen for click event and trigger a state change on the parent depending on the direction.

The first option is to pass each `Arrow` component an arrow function as the `onClick` handler with the corresponding direction:

```
  switchItem = dir => {
    this.setState(pv => ({ item: (pv.item += dir) }));
  };


  <Arrow left onClick={() => this.switchItem(-1)} />
  <Arrow right onClick={() => this.switchItem(1)} />
```

This is quite elegant but cause performance issue due to the function being re-created at each render. The same problem apply to currying.

So the second option is to declare a specific handler for each case:

```
  previousItem = () => {
    this.setState(pv => ({ item: (pv.item -= 1) }));
  };

  nextItem = () => {
    this.setState(pv => ({ item: (pv.item += 1) }));
  };

  <Arrow left onClick={this.previousItem} />
  <Arrow right onClick={this.nextItem} />
```

This cause no performance issue but is very verbose and not very reusable (what if we have 10 different arrows with 10 different directions)

Is there other (better) options for doing that ? If not what should be the preferred way ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

[As stated in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29810951/6499571) you can either use the arrow functions (**the performance problems will usually be unnoticeable**) or do it the React way: creating a new component or modifying the one you have. In this case, you could change your `Arrow` Component so that the handler function  of the component calls the function you send it with an `itemValue` that you also provide as a prop:

```
  <Arrow left onClick={this.switchItem} itemValue={-1} />
```

Then, in the `Arrow` Component you could do something like this in the function where you handle the click:

```
  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.onClick(this.props.itemValue);
  }
```

This is a more elegant and reusable solution than the second one that you proposed and the performance would be great. However, I would probably stick to the arrow function unless you know that many components will be rendered.

Comment: I explored this options too, however this prevent  `Arrow` from being a stateless functional component

Comment: It can be completely stateless anyway, since this function only depends on props! You could also create a wrapper component for the Arrow component with this logic in case you don't want it to be there for whatever reason.

Comment: The performance would be great anyway. There is no performance issue in the original post in the first place. The OP is just creating a problem that doesn't exist. This is just adding more bloat to a code that doesn't need it. Also, if you're creating another component, then at least make two separate - `ArrowLeft` and `ArrowRight` with logic and appearance encapsulated in them. That way, you don't need to pass 3 props to each of them, but only one.

Comment: @HonzaKalfus What do you mean no performance issue ? No perceptible performance issue or not at all ?

Comment: @ThéoChampion No perceptible issue. Your code will be probably like a few microseconds slower. You shouldn't really worry about it and focus on writing a code that's readable instead ;)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're rendering the `Arrow` components a million times per second, you need not worry about performance. Use whatever is convenient to you. Put readability first. Code is written once, but read over and over many times.