# Binding this on method receiving parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

I have an event handler which calls a fat arrow function to run a method.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  sayHi = msg => {
    console.log(msg);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.sayHi('Hi')}>Console Hi!</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I´m learning about contexts and bind() and, I want to convert this example to bind this. My problem is with the parameter that I´m passing when the fat arrow function executes the method, aka, 'Hi'

Is there a way to keep something like this...

```
<button onClick={this.sayHi('Hi')}>Console Hi!</button>
```

I tried different ways without good results. Mostly, focused on

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.sayHi = this.sayHi.bind(this);
  }

  sayHi = () => {
    console.log(msg);
  };
```

And yes... I don´t want to move the 'Hi' to the method or constructor.
I´m trying to learn and understand. I will appreciate any kind of help or orientation.

Comment: You shouldn't need `bind` (or even the constructor) if you're using arrow functions. See https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56

Arguably this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29810914/react-js-onclick-cant-pass-value-to-method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React js onClick can't pass value to method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29810914/react-js-onclick-cant-pass-value-to-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing things. There are two cases for your situation and you are trying to use them both.

**Binding to this**

When do you need you bind your function to `this`? If you are calling your function in callback like your button (one of the cases of course) and you need to use `this` in this function then you need to bind it. If you don't use `this` then there is no need to bind it either.

```
sayHi() {
    console.log("hi");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.sayHi}>Console Hi!</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here, you don't need to bind it, also you can use the function with its reference since there is no argument.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "foo",
    }
    this.sayHi = this.sayHi.bind(this);
  }

  sayHi() {
    console.log(this.state.name);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.sayHi}>Console Hi!</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here you are using `this` in the function, so you need to bind it in the constructor or define it as an arrow function.

**Your situation**

Now, your situation: You are defining your function as an arrow one, no need to bind it anymore if you will use `this` there. But you are not using it, then no need to use an arrow function. Also, you need to pass an argument to it. So, you need to find a way to accomplish this.

The first method, use an arrow function for `onClick`. Since if you don't use a callback here you can't use `click`.

```
sayHi(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.sayHi("hi")}>Console Hi!</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If you use like `this.sayHi("hi")` then this function is invoked in the first render, not with a click.

You can use `.bind` here as a second method also.

```
sayHi(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.sayHi.bind(null,"hi")}>Console Hi!</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

See, we use bind but did not use `this` since we don't need it. We are not using `this` in our `sayHi` function.

Comment: thanks a lot. It really helped to clarify my mental mess.