# React - How to explicitly pass event from onSubmit without Lambdas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint, tslint

In our project, we currently have the following tslint rule: `jsx-no-lambda`

When I need to capture `event` from onSubmit,

My code looks similar to this:

```
public handleLogin = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
}

public render() {
    return(
        <form onSubmit={(event) => this.handleLogin(event)}>
            ...
}
```

This can be solved by removing the arrow function in the jsx like this:

```
<form onSubmit={ this.handleLogin }
```

Is there a more elegant solution to readability here?  More specifically, letting the reader know where `event` is coming from in this line: `<form onSubmit={ this.handleLogin }`

Additionally, how would one pass additional parameters to `handleLogin`?

Comment: Relevant question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29810914/react-js-onclick-cant-pass-value-to-method

Comment: If you define your handleLogin as a method in your class component, that is exactly the way to do it. That tecnique has, also, the performance benefit of not generating an on-the-fly function at each render.

Comment: Sorry for lack of more background, handleLogin is defined in my Component class.

Answer (score 0):

yeah basically after bidning your function to the construnctor like this:

```
constructor() {
  //your other stuff
  this.handleLogin = this.handleLogin.bind(this);
}
```

your can define your function like the following:

```
function handleLogin(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   // do anything that you want
}
```

and finally your component will be like:

```
<form onSubmit={ this.handleLogin }
```

now answering your questions, basically all the information from the event will be on the  `e`, like who called, where, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  However, I want to be more explicit to the reader when they are looking at the render function.  My question is asking if it's possible to explicitly state that `event` being passed into `handleLogin` in the `<form>` component.  `<form onSubmit={ this.handleLogin }` just feels hacky becuase a person might not know where `event` is coming from.  (your answer is already in my question, by the way.)

Comment: I'm afraid that, then, no. You have the two options that you already know: the lambda or the callback, no more, sorry.

Comment: :( thank you @0xc14m1z, I feel that it's a little bit of an oversight since this is such a common pattern in React codebases.  I'll have to revisit this again in the future.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to use the lambda function there, you can use regular function syntax:

```
<form onSubmit={ function (event) { this.handleLogin(event) } }>
```

Then you'll have to bind the `handleLogin` function in the constructor (otherwise you lose the class `this` context):

```
constructor() {
  ..
  ..
  this.handleLogin = this.handleLogin.bind(this);
}
```

and then you won't get the `jsx-no-lambda` tslint error.

> Keep in mind that passing a function to props will cause a creation of
>   the function each time the component renders, which may have performance
>   implications.

See more information [Passing function to components](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html)

Comment: I believe this is still the same thing as `<form onSubmit={ (event) => { this.handleLogin(event) } }>

Comment: but you wanted to get rid of the lambda, didn't you?

Comment: Yes, I do.  However, your solution: `function (event) { this.handleLogin(event) }` IS in fact a lambda function.  It is also what `(event) => { this.handleLogin(event) }` would transpile down to from es6 to es5.

Comment: Additionally, I also tried your solution and ran my linter just in case for both our sanity;  The `jsx-no-lambda` error still occurs.