# Get id of item on which button was clicked reactjs javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object array like this( in Reactjs functional component) which has this guys :

```
--------comments (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

0(pin):{comment:'1',commentid:264}
1(pin):{comment:'2',commentid:265}
2(pin):{comment:'5',commentid:266}
3(pin):{comment:'1',commentid:267}
4(pin):{comment:'2',commentid:268}
5(pin):{comment:'test',commentid:269}
```

I have them displayed on page.
I want to get id of the object i click.
Here is my function.

```
const deleteComment = (id : Number) => {
    console.log('--------id', id);
}
```

I tried to do map,filter or foreach but nothing worked,any suggestions please?

```
<ul>
                        {
                            comments.map((items: any) => {
                                return (
                                    <p
                                        key={uuidv4()}
                                    >Comment : {items.comment}
                                    <button onClick={() => {deleteComment(items.commentid)}}>Delete</button>
                                    </p>
                                );
                            })}
                    </ul>
```

Update (I restarted the app and everything works fine now)

Comment: We'd love to help you. But you need to provide more details. Your React components for instance and how you use (or where) this `deleteComment` function. Those 2 snippets without any context are not very useful.

Comment: Sorry i will fix it

Comment: Generally it would take a form similar to this `onClick={() => deleteComment(/* pass commentId */)}`

Comment: You are probably mapping the array and rendering them right? So, within an `onClick` you can easily do this: `onClick={() => deleteComment(comment.commentid }` Since you are mapping the comments, you have a `comment` (or whatever the name you give in map) variable there.

Comment: Yes I'm mapping it, i will try it thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React js onClick can't pass value to method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29810914/react-js-onclick-cant-pass-value-to-method)

Comment: I tried to do that way but it is giving me undefined,I think it because I need to find index first

Comment: BTW, once you get your issue sorted out you might not want to `key={uuidv4()}` as this will generate a new key *every* render cycle and defeat the purpose of using a react key in the first place.

Comment: It still screams that every element needs it own key lol,but i still could not solve my current issue

Comment: The way you are doing (updated question) should work. Maybe a sandbox would be useful. I'm pretty sure if I move your snippet to a sandbox it would work. Also, I was going to warn about `uuid4()` part. You already have a `commentid` (I assume which is unique), use it.

Comment: Is the console that gives you undefined or the comments inside the ul tag?

Comment: Nvm I restarted application and it worked,thank you all for your time and patience

Answer (score 1):

on your `deleteComment` function , I assume that you are passing the `id` of clicked comment to the function, you need to do something like this:

```js
const deleteComment = (id : Number): void => {
   const foundComment = comments.find(item => item.commentid === id)
}
```

this would give you the clicked item, for deleting it , you need to find the index first and then slice the array of comments and set it in your state or return it of what ever you need to do, in below code snippet i try to remove it from comments array:

```js
const deleteComment = (id : Number): void => {

    /** this would give you the index of found item, other vise it would return -1 */
    const foundIndex = comments.findIndex(item => item.commentid === id)

    if(foundIndex !== -1) {
       
       const newCommentsArr = [
           ...comments.slice(0, foundIndex),
           ...comments.slice(foundIndex + 1, comments.length - 1)
       ]

       /** you can setState the `newCommentsArr` or do what ever you want with it */
      
    }

}
```

Comment: OP already commented that the problem has been solved. Also, if the `index` will be used, it can be passed directly from the click handler but with the existence of a comment id, bothering with indices is a lot of work. The `commentid` and a `filter` method can be used.

Comment: `‍‍filter` would always return an array, and if you try to find with filter, you might select the first index if it finds the comment, but if you use find , it would return the item it self!

Comment: `comments` is already an array, so returning an array is not a problem. We don't need any `find` or `index` if we use `filter` Example: `const newComments = comments.filter(comment => id !== comment.commentid);`