# How to pass a key value into the onchange handler for a select dropdown

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, key

I'm mapping an array[key,val] to dynamically create  dropdowns. I want to pass the key from the select onChange handler so I can store the selected value in the correct index in the array. How do I pass the key.

```
 AdditionQueryArray.map((val, key) => {
    <Select
        onChange={this.AdditionalFieldHandleChange(key)}
        isMulti
        options={this.state.fieldOptions}
    />
}

AdditionalFieldHandleChange = (selectedOption,key) => {// saving selected option in array by key here}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
AdditionQueryArray.map((val, key) => {
    <Select
        onChange={this.AdditionalFieldHandleChange(key, event)}
        isMulti
        options={this.state.fieldOptions}
    />
}

AdditionalFieldHandleChange = (key, event) => {
const val = event.target.value //this will be the selected value
// saving selected option in array by key here
}
```

This way can be used for all types of form fields, be it input or selections.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the answer you need:
[React js onClick can't pass value to method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29810914/react-js-onclick-cant-pass-value-to-method)

example:

```
AdditionQueryArray.map((val, key) => {
    <Select
        onChange={() => this.AdditionalFieldHandleChange(key)}
        isMulti
        options={this.state.fieldOptions}
    />
}

AdditionalFieldHandleChange = (selectedOption,key) => {// saving selected option in array by key here}
```

Maybe add the "val" option to the arguments because you have two arguments in your function definition?