# ReactJS map function cannot find property of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm still learning ReactJS. I'm challenging myself to write a very basic todo app (as one does) and I'm having an issue calling an onClick function.

```
var List = React.createClass({

  handleClick: function () {
    alert("Clicked!");
  },

  render: function () {

    var list = this.props.items;
    var items = list.map(function(item){
      return (
        <li style={{borderBottom:'1px solid red'}}>
          <label onClick={this.handleClick}>
            <input type="checkbox" />
            {item}
          </label>
        </li>
      );
    });

    return (
      <ul>{items}</ul>
    )
  }
});
```

The issue here is that `onClick={this.handleClick}` cannot be called because it is not inside the return call in the render function. 
What do I need to do to access handleClick from inside the map function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OnClick Event binding in React.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27397266/onclick-event-binding-in-react-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're running into is that your call to `list.map` will invoke the passed function with a different `this` than you have in your `render` method.

An easy fix is to grab `this` in the outer scope and stash it in a variable, then use that variable in your inline function.

```
render: function () {
    var self = this;
 // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    var list = this.props.items;
    var items = list.map(function(item){
      return (
        <li style={{borderBottom:'1px solid red'}}>
          <label onClick={self.handleClick}>
                       // ^^^^
            <input type="checkbox" />
            {item}
          </label>
        </li>
      );
    });

    return (
      <ul>{items}</ul>
    )
}
```

Comment: that's a nice trick. it feels a little too easy - are there any downsides to this?

Comment: @MattSaunders this is a pretty common pattern in pre-ES2015 code. It essentially does the same thing as what an ES2015 arrow function would do, you're just doing it by hand. There are other options (rebinding, passing `this` to `map`, etc) but this way is similarly performant and at least as readable.

Answer (score 2):

> **The second argument for the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function is a value to define the
>   scope of `this` when executing the callback.:** 
>   [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)( *callback( currentValue, index, array)*, **value_for_this/scope_to_run_in** )

So you can modify your `map` function as follows:

```
var items = list.map(function(item){
  return (
    <li style={{borderBottom:'1px solid red'}}>
      <label onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        {item}
      </label>
    </li>
  );
}, this);
```

---

> You could also ***use an arrow function*** which where `this` is
>   implicitly bound:

```
var items = list.map((item) => {
  return (
    <li style={{borderBottom:'1px solid red'}}>
      <label onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        {item}
      </label>
    </li>
  );
});
```

Comment: That resolves the issue, but now the click is firing on page load as well (so getting 3 alerts in a row, one per list item, on page load)

Comment: That _is_ strange. You're not invoking the handleClick when setting it on the onClick by defining it with parenthesis ( onClick = {this.handleclick()} ) , are you?

Answer (score 0):

You should bind `this` explicitly to the `handleClick` function to be referring to the React component not the map function, so you can refactor your code as follow:

```
var items = list.map(renderListItem.bind(this));
```

And add `renderListItem` method in your React class as follow:

```
renderListItem(item) {
  return (
    <li style={{borderBottom:'1px solid red'}}>
      <label onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        {item}
      </label>
    </li>
  );
}
```