# I am getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeNote' of undefined even after binding removeNote in the constructer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have bound the removeNote function in the constructor, but I still get the cannot read property error.

```
 class Wall extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                noteDataArray: ['Note value 1 yay','2 notes']
            };
            this.removeNote = this.removeNote.bind(this);
        }

        saveNote(value, index) {
            var temp = this.state.noteDataArray;
            temp[index] = value;
            this.setState({noteDataArray: temp});
        }

        removeNote(index) {
            var temp = this.state.noteDataArray;
            temp.splice(index, 1);
            this.setState({noteDataArray: temp});
        }

        render() {
            return (
                    <div className="Wall">
                        {this.state.noteDataArray.map(function (value, index) {
                            return (
                                    <Notes key={index} index={index} removeit={this.removeNote} >
                                        {value}
                                    </Notes>
                            );
                        })}
                    </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

When I use the same binding method in another component , it works.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40639996/2902660

Comment: Also keep in mind that state is async, and using it to calculate new state can lead to inconsistency. So to be sure you're having up-to-date date, you should use it like: `this.setState((prevState) => { var temp = prevState.noteDataArray; temp[index] = value; return { noteDataArray: temp } })` (more details: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Answer (score 1):

Try using an arrow function when you are mapping through `this.state.noteDataArray` like so:

```
{this.state.noteDataArray.map((value, index) => {
                        return (
                                <Notes key={index} index={index} removeit={this.removeNote} >
                                    {value}
                                </Notes>
                        );
                    })}
```

Have a look in the [MDN article about arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this)

> Until arrow functions, every new function **defined its own this** value... This proved to be annoying with an object-oriented style of programming.
>
> An **arrow function does not create its own this context**, so this has its original meaning from the enclosing context

Comment: Thanks! you're a lifesaver...If its not too much trouble could you explain or point me towards why that worked?

Comment: I've just updated my answer with explanation straight from the MDN. Let me know if you need further info.

Answer (score 1):

You may have bound `this.remove` but you call it within `Array#map` which creates its own `this` context within each iteration of its callback.

`Array#map` takes a second argument that will be used as `this` within each iteration.

Amending your code as follows should do the trick:

```
this.state.noteDataArray.map(function (value, index) {
  return (
    <Notes key={index} index={index} removeit={this.removeNote} >
      {value}
    </Notes>
  );
}, this);
//    ^---- add this as second argument
```