# How to bind methods

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a counter button but I can't. I know its something to do with binding but I can't find a solution. I tried by using .bind(this) but its does not work.

```js
class Button extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <button onClick={this.props.localHandleClick}>+1</button>
    )
  }
}
class Result extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <div>{this.props.localCounter}</div>
    )
      
  }
}
class Main extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      counter:0
    }
  }
   clickHandler(){
    this.setState({counter:                   
    this.state.counter+1});
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <Button localHandleClick={this.handleClick}/>
        <Result localCounter={this.state.counter} />        
      </div>
    )
      
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <Main />,
  document.getElementById("app")
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Add this to your constructor - `this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OnClick Event binding in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27397266/onclick-event-binding-in-react-js)

Comment: I have tried this. This does not work.

Comment: @KrishnaRana What is the error you get?

Comment: I don't get any error, but the screen is blank

Comment: add this in constructor of main component: `this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)`

Comment: @KrishnaRana you said you don't get an error and the screen is blank? Your question example doesn't appear as blank -- maybe update it with the new code so we can see what the issue is?

Comment: @aug error is the button doesn't work. And when I add this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this) the screen is blank

Comment: @KrishnaRana Did anyone solve your problem? If so, could you please accept the best answer (click the checkmark under the points). That will help other users that come across your question quickly spot the accepted answer and it also gives 15 rep. points to the author (:

Answer (score 1):

Changes:

**1.** Bind `handleClick` method in the constructor of main component.

**2.** There is a name mismatch, you are passing the `handleClick` method but you defined the `clickHandler`. Replace `clickHandler` by `handleClick`.

Check the working snippet:

```js
class Button extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <button onClick={this.props.localHandleClick}>+1</button>
    )
  }
}

class Result extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <div>{this.props.localCounter}</div>
    )
      
  }
}

class Main extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      counter:0
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(){
    this.setState({counter: this.state.counter+1});
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <Button localHandleClick={this.handleClick}/>
        <Result localCounter={this.state.counter} />     
      </div>
    )
      
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Main />,
  document.getElementById("app")
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: let me know if you need any help in this.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [.bind(this)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) on your handler so that `this` refers to the component instead of being `undefined`.

Note this is not specific to React, but the default behaviour of JavaScript class methods, which are not automatically bound.

Also, you are using different names in the handler definition and when you use it in the template.

```js
class Button extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return(
      <button onClick={this.props.localHandleClick}>+1</button>
    );
  }
}

class Result extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return(
      <div>{this.props.localCounter}</div>
    );  
  }
}

class Main extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      counter: 0,
    };
    
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }
  
  handleClick() {
    this.setState({
      counter: this.state.counter + 1,
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <Button localHandleClick={ this.handleClick }/>
        <Result localCounter={ this.state.counter } />        
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

If you are using [Babel's class property transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties), you can declare your handler as follows, and it will be automatically bound:

```
class Main extends React.Component {

    handleClick = () => {
        this.setState({
            counter: this.state.counter + 1,
        });
    };

    constructor(props) { ... }

    render() { ... }
}
```