# Update state of only the clicked element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So my code is :

```
export default class MyClass extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: [
          {id: 101, name:"One", thevalue:11},
          {id: 102, name:"Two", thevalue:22},
          {id: 103, name:"three", thevalue:33}
        ]
    }
  }

  handleOnPress() {
    << HOW DO I CODE THIS ?? >>
    I want to increase the number count in thevalue of the pressed item
  }

  render() {
      return(
        <FlatList
            data = {this.state.data}
            renderItem = {
                ({item}) => 
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleOnPress} >
                    <Text> {item.name} + {item.thevalue} </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            }
        />
    )
  }
}
```

I want to be able to increase the count of the `thevalue` of only the item clicked. So I should do a `setState` right? But how do I know for which item I need to run that on? Do I need to pass the `id` of the item clicked to the function? If yes, how do I do that?

Many thanks.

**UPDATE1:**

```
handleOnPress(id) {
      this.setState({
        thevalue: this.state.thevalue+1
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you provide `item` in the `onPress`? For instance: `{this.handleOnPress(item)}` or similar?

Comment: @JeffHuijsmans you can't call it like that or handleOnPress will be called on render of every item. You need to do something as per my answer :)

Comment: @MattDerrick nice, thanks! I was thinking in the way of another framework :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27397266/onclick-event-binding-in-react-js

Comment: Why not create an item component and handle on press in it? In MyClass just render the list.

Comment: Sorry, did not understand. What do you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to give it an argument so we know what item is to increment:

```
onPress={this.handleOnPress.bind(this, item.id)}
...
handleOnPress(id) {
    // increment id
}
```

or this is a little bit more readable but doing the same thing:

```
onPress={() => this.handleOnPress(item.id)}
```

Comment: I have my function: `this.setState({thevalue: this.state.thevalue+1});` but not working.

Comment: You are literally updating with "thevalue"? You need to update 'data[X].thevalue' where X is position of the object with the same ID.

Comment: I did that. Followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45717081/update-state-of-only-the-clicked-element/45717227#45717227 but it's not updating the data real time. I have to save something in the page and Hot Reloading will do the trick. I want the data to be updated realtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `id` to `onPress` then update the corresponding `thevalue`

```html
export default class MyClass extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: [
          {id: 101, name:"One", thevalue:11},
          {id: 102, name:"Two", thevalue:22},
          {id: 103, name:"three", thevalue:33}
        ]
    }
  }

  handleOnPress(id) {
    let {data} = this.state;
    let idx = data.findIndex(x => x.id == id);
    data[idx].thevalue ++;
    this.setState({data});
  }

  render() {
      return(
        <FlatList
            data = {this.state.data}
            renderItem = {
                ({item}) => 
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.handleOnPress(item.id)} >
                    <Text> {item.name} + {item.thevalue} </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            }
        />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I received `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data[idx].thevalue')` I followed your code

Comment: `onPress={(item) => this.handleOnPress(item.id)}` Have you changed the `onPress` function ?

Comment: No. Exactly same as here. Giving same error for idx

Comment: Could you log out `idx` and `data` to see which one is `null` ?

Comment: `console.log(idx)` returned `1` for any of the item clicked

Comment: how about `console.log(id)` ?

Comment: It returned `undefined`

Comment: My bad. Please change to `onPress={() => this.handleOnPress(item.id)}`

Comment: that seems to be giving proper number of the element in the array, but it doesn't update the value of the `thevalue`. Still returning the same number that was before.

Comment: It is actually working but not in real time. When i do some change in the index.android file and save it (I have Hot Reloading enabled), only then its displayed. Otherwise the original value is displayed.