# ES5 this.method is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-5

I have a typescript 2 class that targets ES5.  I'm getting the err in the subject line in the console when I run it.  The switch statement works fine, but increment() and decrement() methods don't execute.

```
class MyClass extends React.Component{
  ...
  increment() {
    console.log('increment()')
    ...
  }
  decrement() {
    console.log('decrement()')
    ...
  }

  buttonClick(btn) {
    console.log(btn)
    switch (btn) {
        case "prev":
            console.log('switch prev')
            this.decrement();
            //this.decrement;
            break;
        default:
            console.log('switch next')
            this.increment();
            //this.increment; eliminates err but method still doesnt execute
            break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If this is react, try putting `.bind(this)` on your jsx template where you call buttonClick. e.g. `onClick={this.buttonClick.bind(this)}`

Comment: You did not show us where and how you are calling `buttonClick`, which is important

Comment: Thx @gautsch this.buttonClick.bind(this) did the trick.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OnClick Event binding in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27397266/onclick-event-binding-in-react-js)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you bind `this` to your functions so that the value of `this` will be what you expect when you call the functions:

```
class MyClass extends React.Component{
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.increment = this.increment.bind(this)
    this.decrement = this.decrement.bind(this)
    this.buttonClick = this.buttonClick.bind(this)
  }
  increment() {
    console.log('increment()')
  }
  decrement() {
    console.log('decrement()')
  }
  buttonClick(btn) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

You can also use property initialized arrow functions if you prefer:

```
class MyClass extends React.Component{
  increment = () => {
    console.log('increment()')
  }
  decrement = () => {
    console.log('decrement()')
  }
  buttonClick = (btn) => {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I might be wrong but I think `this.buttonClick` needs to be bind not `decrement` or `increment`

Comment: @bennygenel can you explain in detail (or provide a link) why I need to bind buttonClick but not decrement etc.? I had exactly that situation today and it worked but I dont know why.