# React.js event binding in render?

Tags: reactjs

Is it really the react way, to bind user interaction events such as "on click" functions, to html tags, inside your `render` function? Is there a furthermore "react way", for binding (html) element interaction events such that they don't get redefined on every call to `render`?

I would assume there's a performance impact when e.g. animation is involved.

The question is general, but sample code follows (in this context, the `onClick` event binding).

```
  render() {
        return (
            <Animate
              start={() => ({
                x: this.state.x,
                y: this.state.y
              })}

              update={() => ({
                x: [this.state.selected ? this.setX(true) : this.setX(false)],
                y: [this.state.selected ? this.setY(true) : this.setY(false)],
                timing: { duration: 1500, ease: easeCubicInOut },
              })}
            >
              {(state) => {
                const { x, y } = state;
                return (
                    <div onClick={this.reverseSelection} className={this.state.style}
                      style={{
                        WebkitTransform: `translate3d(${x}px, ${y}px, 0)`,
                        transform: `translate3d(${x}px, ${y}px, 0)`,
                      }}
                    >
                    {this.props.name}
                  </div>
                );
              }}
            </Animate>
        )

      }
    }
```

If this is somehow really the recommended way, is there a way to reduce the hypothetical performance impact, if you assume that animation is taking place and we want to be lightweight during animation?

Comment: I recommned reading this:https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56

Shortly, binding in render is not preferable because it will be rebind in every render. You can bind them in the constructor or use the experimental syntax.

Comment: @AliAnkarali does that approach mean that `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);` means that `this.handleChange` would check the event object passed to it, to figure which event it is? not sure how this plays out as the samples I can find still _look like_ they bind inside the JSX of `render`.

Comment: It means, that when the react component is mounted. *this* keyword in the function will be the component not the element. If you won't use *this* you don't need a further binding.

Comment: You can also use the es6 arrow syntax to bind functions to a component, which I find much easier than having to bind it myself in the constructor. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: I think you are asking about the event listeners. Your example is the react way. You can use *addEventListener* as well. But from the docs: *When using React you should generally not need to call addEventListener to add listeners to a DOM element after it is created. Instead, just provide a listener when the element is initially rendered.*
https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! Either way, even in the "constructor approach", in the JSX of `render` I still make the association to the event when rendering its html element, in all examples that I see. Which seems superfluous to me, but maybe unavoidable. In terms of lingo, I would call that "event binding" and it happens on every `render`. Any comments or observations on this? maybe I get the jargon wrong, but it looks like the association is made on every `render`, so not sure what this approach is improving actually.

Comment: From what I understood from the docs, the association is made initially, till the component is unmounted.

Comment: I'd like to assume this means that react.js is somehow smart enough to skip the association by detecting that no change is made to the DOM element that requires re-applying the association. Thinking of how the Virtual DOM updates the DOM, I'm not sure whether such level of sophistication is built into the DOM updating algorithm.