# ReactJS - onClick doesn't call the fucntion inside map() function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, dictionary, onclick

I'm new to React and I can't figure out how I can call a function inside through onClick() on a map loop. Let me show you:

```
  const changeLang = lang => {
    i18n.changeLanguage(lang);
  };
```

I have this function who is responsible to get me languages like English or Portuguese. And what I'm trying to do with the following code is change the language depending on which menu item I choose from a menu. To do this I have the following code:

```
const languages = [
  {
    value: 'pt',
    label: 'Portuguese',

  },
  {
    value: 'en',
    label: 'English',
  }
];

...
{languages.map(option => (
    <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value} onClick={() => this.changeLang (option.value)}>
        {option.label}
    </MenuItem>
))}
```

The problem is that it can't enter in my function `changeLang`, so the language is not chosen, no effect at all. I've tried the console.log and I get nothing in return. I'm pretty sure the problem is on `onClick={() => this.changeLang (option.value)}`, but I can't figured out why. Can you help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OnClick Event binding in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27397266/onclick-event-binding-in-react-js)

Comment: Is this a functional component?

Comment: yes it is, I just didn't introduce all code because it was useless for the question.

Comment: can you please check if 'this' has 'changeLang' function. You can do it by this  onClick={() => console.log(this.changeLang)}

Comment: Is this a class based component?

Comment: If this is a class based component then you need to bind `this` based on the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 1):

If this is functional component then remove this keyword and call directly changeLang function

```
languages.map(option => (
    <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value} onClick={() => changeLang(option.value)}>
        {option.label}
    </MenuItem>
))
```

Comment: Did that sir, nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

This is a functional component, so you need to call `changeLang` and not `this.changeLang`

Comment: Did that... nothing happens.

Comment: Can you elaborate on `nothing happens`?

Comment: when I click in the menu item, nothing happens, like no action no console.log. It just doesn't enter in the function "changeLang"

Comment: Did you configure `react-i18next`

Comment: Can you replicate the issue in a sandbox and share it?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of error do you see in your console?

I immediately see a possible issue with your `changeLang` : you are not returning anything from it. Arrow function have an implicit return only when not using braces syntax :

[image: example of bugged function without return value]

I also see this typo :

```
this.changeLang (option.value)
```

should be

```
this.changeLang(option.value)
```

No space between the function call and its arguments.

Maybe you can try these avenues of investigation, and / or post more details about your component.

Comment: No error sir, It just doesn't call the fuction changeLang.

Comment: Did you try fixing the typo, too ? And as others have mentioned, we would need to see the whole component to offer more help.